# Is it ok to have an array or list returned as a property in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, coding-style

I was reading some of the documentation on MSDN concerning do's and don't with regards to whether something should be implemented as a property or as a method. I ran into one rule in particular that I have a question about.

If "The operation returns an array" use a method (instead of a property).

The page is here: [Choosing Between Properties and Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Use a method where the operation returns an
>   array because to preserve the internal array, you would have to return
>   a deep copy of the array, not a reference to the array used by the
>   property. This fact, combined with the fact that developers use
>   properties as though they were fields, can lead to very inefficient
>   code.

I understand that the get method of the property would return a reference to the array, which would allow the array to be changed even if there is no set.  In the example they give, they are making a deep copy of the array every time the property is accessed, I guess to avoid the possibility of this happening, and this in turn is very inefficient.

It would not be inefficient if the property just returned the reference, and didn't do all the copying, right? And also using a method instead of a property is not going to automatically protect the list from being modified.  It is pretty much the same scenario, you would still need a deep copy.

Is using a property and just returning the reference to the array always bad practice?  What if you want the caller to be able to modify the array, or you do not care if they modify it? Is it still bad and why, and if so what would be the proper way to allow the caller to modify?

Comment: You may also be interested in Eric Lippert's article [Arrays considered somewhat harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx), since it deals with this exact scenario.

Comment: Closely related: [is-it-bad-form-to-return-arrays-in-c-should-i-return-listt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274914/is-it-bad-form-to-return-arrays-in-c-should-i-return-listt)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you allow the caller to modify an internal array through a property?  Yes, of course, but you will take on a slew of possible issues.  How you handle those issues and what you can live with is up to you.

The MSDN advice is correct in a very strict sense.  That said I have seen `List<T>` and `T[]` properties returned before from classes.  If your class is a very simple POCO, this is not a big issue because then those classes are just raw data and there's no real business logic to affect.

That said, if I'm returning a list, and I don't want anyone to mess with the internal list, I either return a deep copy every time, or a `ReadOnlyCollection`, or an iterator.  For example, there's lots of places I cache web service request calls, and when i return a cache item, I do NOT want the caller modifying that data or they'll modify what I'm caching.  Thus there I make deep copies (which is still faster than the overhead of the web service call).

You just have to know whether your usage requires the safety or not.  Is the class only for internal consumption?  Or is it designed to be consumed by a wider audience and you have no idea what they are going to do with it?  Those type of questions may drive your response.

Sorry for a "it depends" answer, but it truly does depend on what your goal is and if the internals of the class are sensitive to change.

*UPDATE*  You can also return an iterator, I'd avoid returning IEnumerable as a superclass up-cast because it can be cast back down, but if you return an iterator instead (like using Skip(0)) you are safe (aside from still being able to modify the contained objects of course).

For example:

```
public IEnumerable<T> SomeList 
{
    get { return _internalList.Skip(0); }
}
```

Is better than:

```
public IEnumerable<T> SomeList
{
    get { return _internalList; }
}
```

Because the later can still be cast back to `List<T>` or whatever it was, while the first is an iterator and can't be modified.

Comment: Thanks for the info about ReadOnlyCollection,I had never heard of that one before, but it works like a charm. I will remember that next time I don't want anyone messing with a list.  That is a good tip.  For the most part the things I work on I actually don't really want people to modify the lists themselves, but never actually bothered me that they could set them, and having the array be returned from a method does not automatically protect it from being modified.  To me a property is a type of method.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Yeah I mean I am guilty of this, and it has not caused and issue so far but I did not know there was an easy way to make a list read only.  Does the ReadOnlyCollection cause any type of performance hit?

Comment: A little.  It wraps an IList<T> inside a wrapper class, so there's a slight overhead in delegating the calls to the underlying IList<T>.

Comment: One more question for you, if you don't mind.  If you can use ReadOnlyCollection to protect your list with little overhead, then why would you want to make a deep copy.  Is there any other benefit other than for the caller to be able to change the list, but still not be able to affect the internal state?

Comment: @Chris No, there is no other benefit. Like you said, the benefit of returning a deep copy is that the caller can now read and write to that data structure but the original cannot be modified. A "possible" extra benefit is if the caller wants to use a certain data type to pass into another method, etc, but that is just speculation.

Comment: I guess one would use Collection<T> when the property should also work together with Xmlserializer

Comment: @Rolf I think we're agreed... "A possible extra benefit is if the caller wants to use a certain data type to pass into another method, etc, but that is just speculation. "

Comment: `ReadOnlyCollection` would not protect against modification of the contained objects though, whereas a deep copy would.  Say you have a `ReadOnlyCollection<MyObject> cantTouchMe` you could still do `cantTouchMe[0].SomeProperty = somethingElse' It just prevents adding/removing from the collection.

Comment: Makes sense @Davy8 I guess a deep copy is really the only way to prevent modifying the object contained in such a list.

Comment: @Chris: Another good way to create an immutable collection (not immutable objects, but a collection) is to return as IEnumerable<T> the result of Skip(0).  This returns an iterator, which cannot be modified.  Better than just returning list directly as IEnumerable<T> since the later can be cast back to list.

Comment: It massively irritates me that .NET doesn't have baked in deep cloning and that all of the cloning solutions suck. It is absolutely unacceptable that we're on .NET4 and still don't have a native clone operation.

Comment: @Chris: it would be nice if it were all built in, but I think the designers deliberately left it out so that the user would have to consider the performance implications.  And how deep should an automatic clone go?  I'm not saying it wouldn't be great to have, but it could open up another can of worms too.

Comment: @James Michael Hare how deep should it go? It should copy all of the memory associated with your object and drop it in a 2nd location. That should be built in. The solutions of manually implementing graph crawlers, potentially with IL generation is absurd, so the only ready to go solution is the BinaryFormatter which has terrible performance compared to what should just be copy memory, done.

Comment: @Chris: as I said, I don't deny it wouldn't be useful, but it could also be very expensive if used willy-nilly.  Personally, I think it would be better if we could have the concept of a const reference like C++ has.  That way wouldn't need to copy, but wouldn't be able to call mutating members either.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: If .net allowed field declarations to specify whether they encapsulated identity, mutable state, both, or neither, there would be almost no ambiguity: fields which identify mutable state must be recursively cloned; those which encapsulate identity must not.  If a field encapsulates both, the containing object cannot be cloned in isolation.  Resolving most of the remaining ambiguity would require the ability to specify, for an object which encapsulates the mutable state of something like a `List<T>`, whether the list is being used...

Comment: ...to encapsulate the mutable state of the items, or the identities thereof, both, or neither (an alternative would be to have types `IdentitiesList<T>`, `MutableStatesList<T>`, etc.)  IMHO, Java's erasure of the linguistic distinction between fields which encapsulate mutable state and those which encapsulate identity was not a good thing.  Even if the run-time generally doesn't need such information, it's not possible to write efficient and reliable code without knowing what fields encapsulate what.

Answer (score 2):

If your class's internal state does not depend on the array or list you expose, it is ok to return it as-is. So it should not be possible to sabotage your class by changing the list or array.

If you trust the calling code (i.e. It is written by you), it could be also ok if it gains you performance (measurable and relevant to your app).

If you want to give readonly access, you can return a `ReadonlyCollection` that wraps around the list or array you want to expose.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty much always a bad thing to do but it doesn't stop people doing it (me included).  It's a matter of using a suitable case for the usage scenario.

However, the simplest thing to do to protect the array's encapsulation is to expose only an IEnumerable or ICollection and the methods to mutate the internal array.  See the following example.  I've used List here as the semantics are simpler.

```
class YourClass {
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    public IEnumerable<string> List {
        get { return list; }
    }
    public void Add(string str) {
        list.Add(str);
    }
}
```

As the return type is IEnumerable/ICollection then there is no possibility to mutate the internal state other than via the methods/properties on the class.

The ultimate encapsulation is to copy the entire collection on property access but this is inefficient for most cases.

Semantically speaking, things without much cost which are idempotent and efficient should be assigned a property.  Things that mutate data or have a high execution cost should be a method.

Comment: That is a nice tip as well.  I never thought that as one of the benefits of returning IEnumberable.  I don't think ICollection provides complete protectection, as it is still possible to change the underlying list with clear, add, and remove.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct in your assumption that if you merely return an existing array from a property get, rather than perform a copy, it's no longer a question of efficiency, since doing that is as efficient as returning any other reference type.

As for it being a "bad practice", that largely stems from the reason they describe: that even if you only provide a get accessor on your property, a user can still modify the contents of the array, and thereby mutate the state of your class without your class having a way of validating the changes -- and, worst of all, this consequence of the design is not very obvious unless you already have a deep enough knowledge of C# array semantics.

*If* you can accept that a user will be able to mutate the contents of the array, and *if* you can accept that your class will have no recourse to validate or prevent those changes, then returning the array reference is probably acceptable, just be sure to document that decision and the rationale behind it.

However, unless you *really need* the performance of a raw array, you're probably still better off having your property return a collection class instance instead.  Consumers of your class will still be able to reference items by index using identical syntax, but you retain the capability of making the returned collection immutable, or for providing on-update validation.

Comment: I understand their argument, but I don't really buy it.  The same could be said about exposing any mutable class.  If you expose a mutable class you can modify the properties of it, and the same goes for a List which is a mutable class.

Comment: I agree, returning a List<T> has all the same mutability concerns as returning a T[].   The key difference I see is that if I design an API to return a List<T>, I can start returning a subclass of List<T> in a future version to implement additional functionality, which I can't do with a T[].   (Personally I think it's bad form to return a List<T> too; I usually opt for ICollection<T> or IList<T>, depending on the intended needs of the client, just so I can always swap out the underlying class in future versions.)

Comment: @Timothy: and don't forget that arrays implement `IList<T>` as well, so returning an `IList<T>` gives you the option to return *either* an array or a collection object.

Answer (score 1):

Returning an array or a collection in general using a property is not a bad practice I would say. Especially if the same cached instance is returned every time. However if a new instance is created every time, then a method called something like CreateItems() would make this fact clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the premise that you would want `to preserve the internal array, you would have to return a deep copy of the array, not a reference to the array used by the property.`

In fact it would be quite ["astonishing"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment) if a property did return a deep copy.

It is sometimes the case that you do want to preserve the internal structure and just return a read-only view of it (in the form of an `IEnumerable<T>`) but that's orthogonal to properties.

They make the case that to the outside world, properties should act like fields, and a field would allow modification.  If they're saying that it's bad practice have arrays/lists as fields, that's an entirely different matter unrelated to properties.

Comment: I don't think I would find that astonishing at all.  What about a "view" property that returns a filtered set of the internal values?  You have three options here: (1) make the filtered set unmodifiable; (2) return the filtered set in a new, modifiable collection; or (3) make the filtered set a "live" view that passes modifications to the parent collection.  None of those choices seems significantly more astonishing than the others; none of them seems particularly intuitive, either.

Comment: Also, regarding "properties should act like fields": the entire point of properties is that they **don't** have to act like fields.  That is, they can be synthetic, they can include validation, they can implement various caching strategies.  If you're only using properties to get public-field-like behavior, then you might as well just be using public fields instead.

Comment: Caching is an implementation detail that shouldn't leak, so from the consuming end it is like a field.  Validation I go back and forth on, and I could accept either way as long as it's consistent within the project/organization so either always allow or always disallow doing validation code in getters and setters.

Comment: As far as a "view" property goes, it would have to be named in a way that suggests it's a "view".  If I call `myFarm.Animals.Add(new Pig());` I would expect that the underlying collection was updated.  Furthermore, if I called `myFarm.Animals.First(a=>a.Name == "Bob").Name = "Bill";` I would expect that I modified the actual underlying object, and not just a deep copy of the object.

Comment: @DanielPryden: Even if the filtered set is unmodifiable, it may not be clear whether it represents a live view or a snapshot.  If it's modifiable, attempting to modify it could consistently modify the underlying data, safely not modify the live data (e.g. if it's a modifiable snapshot) but perhaps allow a convenient way of copying its contents back to the data source after modification), or cause weird and arbitrary effects.  It's too bad there's no read-only-array type, since things like I/O often require byte arrays, even though read-only types would be better.