# How to add to end of array C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arrays

How do I add a new `item` from a TextBox and Button on a Windows Form at the end of an `ArrayList` which references a class?

```
private product[] value = new product[4];

value[1] = new product("One",5)
value[2] = new product("Two",3)
value[3] = new product("Three",8)
```

#### Workflow

- Enter new products details into `textbox1`, `textbox2`, `textbox3`
- When I click `Add` the new product gets added to the array:

  `value[1] = new product("One",5)`
  `value[2] = new product("Two",3)`
  `value[3] = new product("Three",8)`
  `value[4] = new product("Four",2)`

What is the code for doing this?

Comment: Correction firstline should be: 
private product[] value = new product[4]

Timmy

Comment: I see that you posted the same comment in response to a few answers saying that you don't want to use a List. Is there any reason why?

Comment: Just beware that value[0] isn't initialized. It might be on purpose, though.

Comment: `private product[] value = new product[4];` means you allocate place for 4 products. Arrays are zero-indexed in C#, so the first assignment line should be `value[0] = new product("One",5)` instead of 1.

Comment: @Timmy please don't post edits in the comments. You can edit your original post with the edit button. Thx

Answer (score 37):

Arrays are fixed size, which means you can't add more elements than the number allocated at creation time, if you need a auto sizing collection you could use `List<T>` or an `ArrayList`

Example:

```
// using collection initializers to add two products at creation time
List<Product> products = new List<Product>{new Product("One",5), new Product("Two",3) };

// then add more elements as needed
products.Add(new Product("Three",8));
```

Comment: Ok guys thanks for all your answers....I do not want to try the List method...I will go with the Array resize...Would I use it the following way in the add button after entering details in textboxes: private void btnAdd_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) { Array.Resize<product>(ref value, 5); }
And how would I use the ArrayList?

Comment: Timmy, you should use whatever makes more sense for you, but just so you know, `List<T>` and `ArrayList` both use internally a private array that is resized using Array.Resize() automatically when adding or removing items.

Comment: Ok Sorry forgot to mention I do not want it to grow to big because its a test at the moment...So about 2 new products will do...
will this work: 
private product[] value = new product[5]; value[0] = new product("One",5) value[1] = new product("Two",3) value[2] = new product("Three",8) 

or like this: 

private product[] value = new product[5]; value[0] = new product("One",5) value[1] = new product("Two",3) value[2] = new product("Three",8) value[3] = new product(textBox1,textBox2) value[4] = new product(textBox1,textBox2)

Answer (score 20):

Use List as other people mentioned.
If you are set on arrays, use

```
Array.Resize<Product>(ref product, your new size);
```

If you're only going to be adding a couple of products (over the lifetime of your array) just do something like

```
Array.Resize<Product>(ref product, product.Length + 1);
```

If you are going to be adding a lot of products, you might want to do something similar to what List does - like this:

```
Array.Resize<Product>(ref product, product.Length * 2);
```

Comment: Ok guys thanks for all your answers....I do not want to try the List method...I will go with the Array resize...Would I use it the following way in the add button after entering details in textboxes: private void btnAdd_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) { Array.Resize<product>(ref value, 5); }

Comment: Note that since a ref parameter is required, this method cannot be used on a property of an object.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need a `List<product>` collection, looking at your code. Then just call the `Add()` method on it

Comment: Ok guys thanks for all your answers....I do not want to try the List method...I will go with the Array resize...Would I use it the following way in the add button after entering details in textboxes: private void btnAdd_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) { Array.Resize<product>(ref value, 5); }

Answer (score 3):

You can't add items to an array, you would have to create a new array that is larger and copy the items to it. There is a method for that, which is somewhat misleadingly named `Resize` as it doesn't actually resize the array:

```
Array.Resize<product>(ref value, 5);
```

If you want to add items to a collection, you should use a List instead:

```
private List<product> value = new List<product>();
value.Add(new product("One",5));
value.Add(new product("Two",3));
value.Add(new product("Three",8));

value.Add(new product("Four",2));
```

Edit:
If you want to resize the array, you might want to increase the size instead of resizing it to a specific value:

```
int index = value.Length;
Array.Resize<product>(ref value, index + 1);
value[index] = ...
```

Comment: Ok guys thanks for all your answers....I do not want to try the List method...I will go with the Array resize...Would I use it the following way in the add button after entering details in textboxes:
private void btnAdd_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Array.Resize<product>(ref value, 5);
        }

Comment: Yes, but using the zero index you would rather resize it to four, or perhaps increasing the size by one (se edit above).

Comment: Are you sure the code is correct? Am gettin errors:
Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Array.Resize<products>(ref products.value[], int)' has some invalid arguments 

and

Error 2 Argument '1' must be passed with the 'ref' keyword

Comment: @Timmy: Corrected. The call should of course have the ref keyword, just like in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are zero indexed, so an array initialized to a size of 4 could only be accessed up to index 3...

If you wanted the array to grow, then you'd have to either initialize the array at least as large as you wanted to be able to grow to, or else you'd have to create a new array with the new larger size and copy the old array over; not very efficient.

In this case, you'd do better to use a collection like a list, rather than an array, so that the size can dynamically increase.

Comment: Ok I know that already but its not working....hmmm?? What could be the problem now if the array indexed is set to [0] to [4]? Do I need to declare it as an empty array at start as so:
value[0] = new product("One",5) value[1] = new product("Two",3) value[2] = new product("Three",8)
value[3] = new product{textbox1,textbox2}

?

Comment: +1  Wow, can't believe I did not catch that too.   @Timmy, your value[1] = new product("One",5) should really read value[0] = new product("One",5)

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I do not want it to grow to big because its a test at the moment...So about 2 new products will do...will this work:
private product[] value = new product[5];

value[0] = new product("One",5)
value[1] = new product("Two",3)
value[2] = new product("Three",8)

or like this:
private product[] value = new product[5];

value[0] = new product("One",5)
value[1] = new product("Two",3)
value[2] = new product("Three",8)
value[3] = new product(textBox1,textBox2)
value[4] = new product(textBox1,textBox2)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably also take a look at [Array versus List: When to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which/1782105)

Answer (score 0):

Array.Resize is not an efficient method. It creates a new array with the new size then copy old array values to the new array and then replaces the old array with the new array.
As you can see this is not a very efficient way of appending an item.

Unless it is a requirement that you have no control on use a List instead of array or create an array with maximum expected dimension from the beginning.

For more explanation consider this example:
You created an array that can hold million items and fill it with objects.
You want to add the million and one object to the array.
You use Array.Resize method to change array size to 1000001.
When the method tries to create a new array of 1000001 items and copy the items from old array to new array you may get an out of memory error because you are trying to have TWO arrays of a million (holding 2 millions objects) in memory at the same time while all the items that you need are one million +1.
Although consider the time and resources lost in creating, copying and replacing.