# Add object to this array of custom Classes C#

Tags: c#, arrays

This is a noob question, I apologize.  I have been trying for a while to figure out how to add an object to this array.  I have an Employee class, and a Salary class that inherits from Emp, and an Hourly class that does.  I created an array like this,

```
        public Employee[] _Employees;
        ...    
        Employee[] _Employees = new Employee[]{ 
        new Hourly("1000", "Harry","Potter", "L.", "Privet Drive", "201-9090", "40.00", "12.00"),
        new Salary("2201", "A.", "A.", "Dumbledore", "Hogewarts", "803-1230", "1200"),
        new Hourly("3330", "R.","Weasley", "R.", "The Burrow", "892-2000", "40", "10.00"),
        new Salary("4040", "R.", "R.", "Hagrid", "Hogwarts", "910-8765", "1000")
                                                    };
```

And now I want to add objects to the array that I have read in from a text file.  I am doing it like this right now;

```
                      if(rstring == "H")
                {
                    string fullName = data.ReadLine();
                    string empNum = data.ReadLine();
                    string address = data.ReadLine();
                    string phoneNum = data.ReadLine();
                    string hrWorked = data.ReadLine();
                    string hrRate = data.ReadLine();

                    string[] splitName = fullName.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });

                    string fName = splitName[0];
                    string mName = splitName[1];
                    string lName = splitName[2];

                     _MyForm._Employees = new Employee[] {new Hourly ( empNum, fName, mName, lName, address, phoneNum, hrWorked, hrRate ) };
```

which doesn't give me any error, but when I look at what is stored in the _Employees class, it just has the info from above and nothing else.  Let me know if I need to explain myself better.  Just let me know if I need to go about it another way, or what I need to do to add the read info to this _Employees class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having an array, you should consider using a [`List<Employee>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).  This will let you *add* any number of elements to the list, without recreating it yourself:

```
private List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
public IList<Employee> Employees { get { return this.employees; } }

// ...
this.employees.Add(new Hourly("1000", "Harry","Potter", "L.", "Privet Drive", "201-9090", "40.00", "12.00"));
// .. Add all
```

Then, when you want to add a new one, you can use:

```
_MyForm.Employees.Add(new Hourly ( empNum, fName, mName, lName, address, phoneNum, hrWorked, hrRate));
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better off using a `List` in this case:

`IList<Employee> _Employees;`

List has the advantage of having an `Add` method which can be used to add new objects to the end of the array.

`_MyForm._Employees.Add(new Hourly(...))`

If you wanted to insert objects at other points in the collection there's also the `Insert` method which takes an index along with the object to be added.

Answer (score 1):

Use the List class as others have pointed out and the Add method. What you have done here:

```
_MyForm._Employees = new Employee[]
```

in your example code is you've *re-assigned* your reference of MyForm._Employees to a new object of type Employee[], not added to it. Your previous reference containing your other valuable employees will have most likely been garbage collected (if nothing else in scope is referencing it).

I would steer clear of arrays to be honest. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the info, here is an article I found in the link you provided [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx)