# C# inheritance and arrays

Tags: c#

I really hope u guys will be able to help me I'm trying to make a program on inheritance and arrays Amma just right the question I've tried it but I can't get the displays correct .......

create a base class  called package with instance variables (packageId, weight, costperounce,senderName,senderaddress,city,recipientName, recipient city ,recipient parish). And here's what's I'm suppose to do

Use inheritance hierarchy to create an application that displays the recipients and senders addresses information. And calculate the transport cost for several packages (weight*costperounce). The application  should contain an array of package objects of class TwoDayPackage and overnight Package. The transport fees for the TwoDayPackage includes a flat rate of $500.00 added to the basic calculation whilst the OverNightPackage includes a flat rate of $1500.00 added to the costperounce multiplied by the weight of the package. Loop through the array to process the package polymorphically.

For each package use properties to obtain the address information of the sender a d the recipient then print the two addresses as they would spare on a mailing labels also. All each package's cost method and print the result. Keep track of the total shipping cost for all packages in the array and display the total when the loop terminates

Plz help me I've at it for almost a week now and help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: stackoverflow was not made to do other peoples work. Please ask us for an answer to a specific problem you're having and give us the code you've made so far.
Please have a look at the faq, too. Especially the first two points about the questions that should or shouldn't be asked here:
http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: I'm writing the code to show u how far I've reached I just need some guidance

Comment: I posted where I'm at so far just want to be able to do the calculations and the inheritance to be displayed and the keeping track of it

Comment: Thanks again any help will be appreciated

Comment: So, what is your question, exactly? You don't understand how to declare arrays in C#? Problems with understanding inheritance, perhaps?

Comment: Inheritance and displaying it through it

Comment: Keeps on sayin theres no definition for sum

Answer (score 4):

perhaps this will help, I felt generous today.

A few things your assignment likely is trying to force you to learn and some links that will go through some of those topics

1. [override vs new](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. [polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx)
3. [inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
4. [Array vs List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which)
5. [Array Resizing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx)

   ```
     class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           //the array method
           var test = new Order();
           test.AddPackage(new OvernightPackage() { WeightInOunces = 10, Sender = new Person() { Name = "Sender"}, Recipient = new Person() {Name = "Recipient"}});
           test.AddPackage(new TwoDayPackage() { WeightInOunces = 16, Sender = new Person() { Name = "Sender" }, Recipient = new Person() { Name = "Recipient" } });
           test.AddPackage(new TwoDayPackage() { WeightInOunces = 10, Sender = new Person() { Name = "Sender" }, Recipient = new Person() { Name = "Recipient" } });
           test.PrintManifestsWithArray();

           //the list way
           test.Packages = new List<Package>(test.PackagesArray);
           test.PrintManifests();


           Console.ReadLine();
       }
   }

   public class Person
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public Address Address { get; set; }
   }

   public class Address
   {
       public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
       public string City { get; set; }
       public string State { get; set; }
       public string ZipCode { get; set; }
   }

   public abstract class Package
   {
       protected Package()
       {
           CostPerOunce = .08;
           WeightInOunces = 0;
       }
       public string Id { get; set; }
       public int WeightInOunces { get; set; }
       public double DeliveryCost { get { return CalculateCost(); } }
       public Person Sender { get; set; }
       public Person Recipient { get; set; }
       public double CostPerOunce { get; set; }
       protected virtual double CalculateCost ()
       {
           return WeightInOunces*CostPerOunce;
       }
   }

   public class OvernightPackage : Package
   {
       public OvernightPackage()
       {
           CostPerOunce = .12;
       }
       protected override double CalculateCost()
       {
           var cost = base.CalculateCost();
           cost += 1500.00;
           return cost;
       }
   }

   public class TwoDayPackage : Package
   {
       protected override double CalculateCost()
       {
           var cost = base.CalculateCost();
           cost += 500.00;
           return cost;
       }
   }

   public class Order
   {
       public List<Package> Packages { get; set; }
       public Package[] PackagesArray
       {
           get { return _thePackages; }
       }

       private Package[] _thePackages = new Package[0];
       public void AddPackage(Package pkg)
       {
           Array.Resize(ref _thePackages, _thePackages.Length + 1);
           _thePackages[_thePackages.Length -1] = pkg;
       }

       public void PrintManifestsWithArray()
       {
           foreach (var package in PackagesArray)
           {
               Console.WriteLine( package.GetType() + ": " + package.DeliveryCost);
           }
       }

       public double TotalCost
       {
           get
           {
               return Packages.Sum(package => (double) package.DeliveryCost);
           }
       }

       public void PrintManifests()
       {
           foreach (var package in Packages)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(package.Sender.Name);
               Console.WriteLine(package.Recipient.Name);
               Console.WriteLine(package.DeliveryCost);
               ///so on and so forth
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: yes, just whipped up something that took a few minutes probably problems with it, but demonstrates inheritance and arrays

Comment: One thing I don't understand with your code I can't see where the arrays r declared

Comment: also, here is something on why I use a List<Package>, a true array sucks to use in reality : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which

Comment: I updated to use an array instead, I left the List<Package> code there as well as you can see the problem with using the array is re-sizing on the fly.  A list comes built for that.  Also, with inheritance you should know the difference between overriding a function and creating a new function.

Comment: Could u edit to only arrays and inheritance plz if it not too much bother

Comment: It keeps on saying there's no definition for some