# What is an "index out of range" exception, and how do I fix it?

Tags: c#, .net, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm getting one of the following errors:

- "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection"
- "Insertion index was out of range.  Must be non-negative and less than or equal to size."
- "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

What does it mean, and how do I fix it?

**See Also**
[IndexOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception)
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception)

Answer (score 44):

### Why does this error occur?

Because you tried to access an element in a collection, using a numeric index that exceeds the collection's boundaries.

The first element in a collection is generally located at index `0`. The last element is at index `n-1`, where `n` is the `Size` of the collection (the number of elements it contains).  If you attempt to use a negative number as an index, or a number that is larger than `Size-1`, you're going to get an error.

### How indexing arrays works

When you declare an array like this:

```
var array = new int[6]
```

The first and last elements in the array are

```
var firstElement = array[0];
var lastElement = array[5];
```

So when you write:

```
var element = array[5];
```

you are retrieving the sixth element in the array, not the fifth one.

Typically, you would loop over an array like this:

```
for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(array[index]);
}
```

This works, because the loop starts at zero, and ends at `Length-1` because `index` is no longer less than `Length`.

This, however, will throw an exception:

```
for (int index = 0; index <= array.Length; index++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(array[index]);
}
```

Notice the `<=` there?  `index` will now be out of range in the last loop iteration, because the loop thinks that `Length` is a valid index, but it is not.

### How other collections work

Lists work the same way, except that you generally use `Count` instead of `Length`.  They still start at zero, and end at `Count - 1`.

```
for (int index = 0; i < list.Count; index++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list[index]);
}
```

However, you can also iterate through a list using `foreach`, avoiding the whole problem of indexing entirely:

```
foreach (var element in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());
}
```

You cannot index an element that hasn't been added to a collection yet.

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Zero");
list.Add("One");
list.Add("Two");
Console.WriteLine(list[3]);  // Throws exception.
```

Comment: Somewhat relevant... [when to use Array vs List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which)

Comment: you may want to mention that indexer can't be used to add new items to the list unlike arrays, it can only be used for modifying existing items. i.e `var list = new List<int>(10); list[0] = 10;` will throw an IndexOutOfRange exception