# How to save data grid values to sql database whole values to one primary key i tried but it doesnt work

Tags: c#

I get a exception "index was out of range. Must be no-negative and less than the size of the collection. parameter name : index

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (txtSubtotal.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Sub Total cannot be Empty", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtSubtotal.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (txtamountdue.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Amountdue cannot be Empty", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtamountdue.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (txtcashgiven.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter the cash given", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtcashgiven.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (txtchange.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Cahange cannot be Empty", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtchange.Focus();
                return;
            }



            con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
            con.Open();


            string cb = "insert Into invoiceTB(InvoiceNo,Date,BillTo,CustomerID,SalesBy,Warranty,ShipTo,SubTotal,AmountDue,CashGiven,Change) VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5,@d6,@d7,@d8,@d9,@d10,@d11)";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(cb);
            cmd.Connection = con;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1",txtInvoice.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2",dateTimePicker1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3",txtBillTo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d4", cmbcustomerID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d5",txtSalesBy.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d6",txtwarranty.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d7",txtshipto.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d8",txtSubtotal.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d9",txtamountdue.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d10",txtcashgiven.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d11",txtchange.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            con.Close();


            for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);

                string cd = "insert Into invoiceTB(ItemCode,Description,Quantity,PriceEach,Amount) VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5)";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(cd);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d1", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d2", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d3", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d4", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d5", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }

            btnSave.Enabled = false;
            btnprint.Enabled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Placed", "Order", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: First of all, next time please be sensitive about formatting. Second, _doesn't work_ is not a good way to ask a question. What do you mean by? You get an exception or error message?

Comment: sorry im new here i get a exception "index was out of range. Must be no-negative and less than the size of the collection. parameter name : index

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you asking but I see a few things;

- You need to use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your first insert statement. That's just execute your code. `ExecuteReader` method returns data. Since you just inserting data, pointless to use it.
- You need to use `@` in your second insert command parameter names in your `AddWithValue` method.
- Use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections and objects.
- `DATE` can be a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)  future releases of SQL Server. You might need to avoid to use it.
- As a best practice, don't use `AddWithValue` method. It might generates unexpected and surprising results. Use [`.Add()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add.aspx) instead. Read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

For your error message, read [What is an "index out of range" exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812679/what-is-an-index-out-of-range-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: i tried everything u said but i get the same exception can u show me a example code that used to save data-grid values to database with the textbox data similar to my code

Comment: @JeromeJacobsFrancis Did you debug your code line by line? It is clearly try to access a value that doesn't inside in your collections boundaries. Please read this question and answer carefully. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812679/what-is-an-index-out-of-range-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it