# System.IndexOutOfRangeException When trying populate a two-dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays

Can any one tell me why I receive a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` from this code?

```
char[,] matrix = new char[80, 18];
for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
    for (int j = 0; i < 18; j++)
        matrix[i, j] = '1';
```

Comment: thats what happens when you copy&paste the for loop without changing all the vars correctly. you missed the `i` in the 2nd loop. should have changed it to `j` as well

Comment: Thats't reason why we always say: _Use the debugger first_

Comment: Also duplicate: [What is an “index out of range” exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812679/what-is-an-index-out-of-range-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 11):

You are checking if i is smaller than 18 in the second for loop

```
char[,] matrix = new char[80, 18];
for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
    for (int j = 0; i < 18; j++) //<-- Right there.
        matrix[i, j] = '1';
```

Change to:

```
char[,] matrix = new char[80, 18];
for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++) //<-- Right there.
        matrix[i, j] = '1';
```

Answer (score 4):

**Problem :** in your second for loop you are checking with variable `i` instead of `j`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
for (int j = 0; i < 18; j++)
               ^^^ should be j
```

Try This:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++)
```

Answer (score 3):

...because you have a typo in 
 for (int j = 0; ***i*** < 18; j++)

Comment: OMG that was embarrassing! Sorry!