# Datagridview add row with cell style programmatically

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewrow, datagridviewcellstyle

`dgvStatus` is a  DataGridView with one column.

Following line is adding new row

```
dgvStatus.Rows.Add("XYZ");
```

But I want to change cell text color so I have written following code

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
style.ForeColor = Color.Red; // the color change
row.DefaultCellStyle = style;
row.Cells[0].Value = "XYZ";
dgvStatus.Rows.Add(row);
```

But this code giving error -

[image]

How to fix it.

**UPDATE:**

When I changed my code according to `@ASh`'s answer

```
dgvStatus.Rows.Add(row);
row.Cells[0].Value = "XYZ";
```

Then it is giving following error -

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812679/what-is-an-index-out-of-range-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

row doesn't have cells until you add it to grid

```
dgvStatus.Rows.Add(row);
row.Cells[0].Value = "XYZ";
```

UPDATE

if it doesn't work, try this:

```
int idx = dgvStatus.Rows.Add("test");
var row = dgvStatus.Rows[idx];
DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
style.ForeColor = Color.Red; // the color change
row.DefaultCellStyle = style;
```