# Access loops int and use it another function

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use a loop to place my player in the seat that is empty which works fine but I'm trying to set a bool to false when the player leaves it but I can't seem to get access to it

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
>   GetIn.ExitObject () (at Assets/GetIn.cs:118) GetIn.Update () (at
>   Assets/GetIn.cs:55)

```
    public int whatSeat;
    Transform TheObject;

    positions = TheObject.GetComponent<GetInObject>().PosInObect;
    for (whatSeat = 0; whatSeat < positions.Length; whatSeat++)
    {
        if (positions[whatSeat].isOccupied == false)
        {
            transform.parent = positions[whatSeat].pos;
            positions[whatSeat].isOccupied = true;
        }
    }
```

and then in another function I want to access the same `whatSeat` variable to turn it to false when you exit

```
positions[whatSeat].isOccupied = false;
```

but that is where the error crops up I don't know how to solve this

Comment: What is the value of `whatSeat` when you debug your code? Are you sure your `positions` have this index? Related: [What is an “index out of range” exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812679/what-is-an-index-out-of-range-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Have you tried adding a "break;" after the "positions[whatSeat].isOccupied = true;" line? Then the loop will find the first unoccupied seat and finish. Leaving whatSeat as the newly occupied seat.

Comment: ok after putting in some debugs the whatseat changes to 1 so how do i go about adding this break in?

Comment: Also make sure you don't use the same `whatSeat` variable to loop trough seats for multiple players or units (I assume there are more units since there are more seats).

Comment: ok that break fixed it thanks do you wanna put that as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    public int whatSeat;
    Transform TheObject;

    positions = TheObject.GetComponent<GetInObject>().PosInObect;
    for (whatSeat = 0; whatSeat < positions.Length; whatSeat++)
    {
        if (positions[whatSeat].isOccupied == false)
        {
            transform.parent = positions[whatSeat].pos;
            positions[whatSeat].isOccupied = true;
            break;   // Adding break here
        }
    }
```

Once you exit the loop, whatSeat will hold the value of the newly occupied seat.

Comment: ok i cant see the accept button atm as im using a networked computer that using internet explorer from like 2006 so when i get home ill accept it