# Go to a link when GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, response.redirect, selectedindex

I want that when a user presses select from the gridview to redirect him to a site, and the site parameter to be taken from the first row of gridview. I have this code, but I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
>   and less than the size of the collection.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    string strCell = row.Cells[1].Text;
    string myPageUrl = "Meci.aspx?ID=" + strCell;
    Response.Redirect(myPageUrl);
}
```

Please tell me how to fix the error or what other code to use!

It is different than [What is an "index out of range" exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812679/what-is-an-index-out-of-range-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) because the answer there is that the index value is not correct, but I tried with other values (0,1,2.3,4,5 ...) but this error keeps coming every time.
 Randul este cel selectat, iar celula 1 exista si are o valoare, mai mult de atat ieri mi-a mers codul respectiv pe aceliasi pagina si acelasi gidview!

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/24812679/447156

Comment: Do you want retrieve the url from the first row or the first column of the selected row? ..keep in mind that indexes are 0-based

Comment: On the first column is the id and want to select it to be redirected to a page that has more details that turn

Comment: Ok, you have indexing by 0. The index of the first column is 0, the second 1, and so on...