# How can I fix error "Index was out of range must be nonnegative and less than the size of the collection"? in C#

Tags: c#, indexoutofrangeexception

How to fix error "Index was out of range must be nonnegative and less than the size of the collection"?

```
    // Create new List called _identifiers
    private List<string> _identifiers = new List<string>();

    // Add identifiers to the Identifiable object
    public IdentifiableObject (string[] idents)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<idents.Length; i++)
        {
            idents [i] = _identifiers [i];
        }
    }
```

[image: Screenshot of IndexOutOfRange]

Comment: `_identifiers` is empty, so attemtping to access `_identifiers[0]` will pop the error

Comment: I recommend scrolling down the page a bit and following some of the links under the "Related" heading in the sidebar.

Comment: We need some context. At first glance, your list `_identifiers` is empty, so even `_identifieres[0]` throws this exception because _there is no 0th element in your list_

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812679/what-is-an-index-out-of-range-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: I have the feeling that you want instead __identifiers.Add/(idents[i]);_

Comment: Thanks for help, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the length of your `_identifiers`-array is less than the length of your `idents`-array. Thus, while you're looping through all identifiers until the max length of `idents`, you try to access an inexistent inxed of `_identifiers`.

In your case, `_identifiers` is empty, so it's clearly less long than your `idents`