# Function, which deletes all code comments

Tags: c#, algorithm, function, comments

I need to do a function which deletes all comments from the text(code). My code is almost finished, but it doesn't work if comment starts in the first line of the file.  It says index out of bounds, I tried changing `for` loops to start from 1 and then `if` to`(text[i] == '/' && text[i - 1] == '/')` but it doesn't work.
Any suggestion how can I fix that or improve my code because it looks weird.

```
public void RemoveComments(string text)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                if (text[i] == '/' && text[i + 1] == '/')
                {
                    text = text.Remove(i, 2);
                    for (int j = i; j < text.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (text[j] != '\n')
                        {
                            text = text.Remove(j, 1);
                            j--;
                        }
                        else if (text[j] == '\n')
                        {
                            text = text.Remove(j, 1);
                            j--;
                            while (text[j] == ' ')
                            {
                                text = text.Remove(j, 1);
                                j--;
                            }
                            i = j;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                else if (text[i] == '/' && text[i + 1] == '*')
                {
                    text = text.Remove(i, 2);
                    for (int j = i; j < text.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (text[j] != '*' && text[j + 1] != '/')
                        {
                            text = text.Remove(j, 1);
                            j--;
                        }

                        else if (text[j] == '*' && text[j + 1] == '/')
                        {
                            text = text.Remove(j, 2);
                            j = j - 2;
                            while (text[j] == ' ')
                            {
                                text = text.Remove(j, 1);
                                j--;
                                if (text[j] == '\n')
                                {
                                    text = text.Remove(j, 1);
                                    j--;
                                }
                            }
                            i = j;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
```

EDIT: Now I did many experiments and I found that the problem is with(in // loop) I needed this loop this to fix some small aligment problems:

```
while (text[j] == ' ')
{
    text = text.Remove(j, 1);
    j--;
}
```

Test.txt file.

```
//int a;
int c; //int d;
Console.Write/*Line*/("Hhehehe");
if(1>0)
/*ConsoleWriteLine("Yes")*/
//Nooo
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an "index out of range" exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812679/what-is-an-index-out-of-range-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I think you missed the case of block comment ?

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Which line of the code throws this exception?

Comment: It removed all comments from the big code, but then I added a comment to first line of the code and it crashed.

Comment: @AntoineV: `else if (text[i] == '/' && text[i + 1] == '*')`

Comment: Why don't you simply split the input text to the newline characters, then if you find the double // you can remove everything from that point on. Of course still is not enough to handle the _/* .....many lines here ... */_ block comment style.

Comment: Is this only for c# code? If so consider using the Microsoft Compiler Services (Rosyln) to parse and manipulate comments.

Comment: @D0mm: i guess it would help if you'd add a small sample file with 2-3 lines that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I means block comment likes : /*FilePath = fbd.FileName; enter await Task.Run(() => CallWebService());*/

Comment: Ok, I will add small example of file text(code)

Comment: `i < text.Length -1` to avoid testing the index `[i + 1]` out of range

Comment: @AntoineV: well, he removes the part between `/*` and `*/` in the code that i have shown. I havent testedt it though, but on a first sight it looks like it is what you are missing.

Comment: Sorry it can't be that simple, you have to implement a parser: what if you have a code like this: `string demo = "//demo//";`

Comment: One of the rare occasions that I'd recommend using RegEx ...

Comment: @Fildor: because Regex understands C# code?

Comment: Another Question: Do you also want to remove Documentation? ( `/// <summary> ... `) ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter No. But if I had to do it, I wouldn't start implementing it with a bunch of for loops. I'd do search and remove with regex patterns. Seems easier to me. Of course, using Roslyn as Crowcoder suggests may work even better, but I am not familiar with that.

Comment: @Fildor: i don't even know all the edge cases that are possible with C# code. `demo = "//demo//";` is not a comment but `demo = "//demo"; //";` is. You had to rebuild a compiler with regex, have fun.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Meh, I guess you are right. So you would recommend Roslyn, too?

Comment: @Fildor: I can tell you from experience that building a lexical scanner for this is a whole lot easier than trying to do it with regex. But if I had to do it today, I'd use Roslyn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have C# code files. Thus you can use the power of [Roslyn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/get-started/syntax-transformation). Simply parse code file into syntax tree and then visit that tree with visitor which skips comments:

```
var code = File.ReadAllText("Code.cs");
SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();
var codeWithoutComments = new CommentsRemover().Visit(root).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(codeWithoutComments);
```

Visitor:

```
class CommentsRemover : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    public override SyntaxTrivia VisitTrivia(SyntaxTrivia trivia)
    {
        switch(trivia.Kind())
        {
            case SyntaxKind.SingleLineCommentTrivia:
            case SyntaxKind.MultiLineCommentTrivia:
                return default; // new SyntaxTrivia()  // if C# <= 7.0
            default:
                return trivia;                 
        }            
    }
}
```

Sample code file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    /* Sample
       Multiline Comment */
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Comment
            Console.Write/*Line*/("Hello, World!"); // Print greeting
            /*ConsoleWriteLine("Yes")*/
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write("Hello, World!");

        }
    }
}
```

Notes: As you can see, after removing comments from the lines which had nothing except comment, you get empty lines. You can create one more visitor to remove empty lines. Also consider to remove XML comments as well.

Comment: Woah, thanks, it is an interesting and new way for me to learn! :o

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop based on text.Length

for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)

But inside of the loop you are shorten the text. At a certain point it is smaller as the origin text.Length and you running out of index I guiess

Comment: In C# for loops it always checks the condition before continuing, so this is not a problem