# c# "greater than" and "greater than and equal" difference

Tags: c#

(C#)

ScreenShots:
https://pasteboard.co/JGKU92J.jpg
https://pasteboard.co/JGKUrQd.jpg

I wrote in first one < and the other one <=
Why when I wrote <= like that it gaveme error?
Sorry for my Englsih

Code:
https://www.paste.org/113948

Comment: 1) include code ***in your question*** - as ***text***. 2) error - ***what error***? 3) read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 4) because we start counting at 0. so an array (or string) with 3 elements has the elements 0, 1 and 2. _no_ element 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an "index out of range" exception, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812679/what-is-an-index-out-of-range-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget 0 when counting the entries of a list. When you are asking for the length of a List, Array, String,... the program gives you back the amount of values that are in there. But you cannot check position `metin[metin.length()]` as it will never be defined, because `metin[0]` is already a position.

The last position of your array is `metin[metin.length()-1]`, but when you are doing the `for` loop until `i` is greater or equal than `metin.length()` you are asking for one more, which is undefined and hence the error.