# String into char on 2D array (java)

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to fill a 2D char array with 5 words. Each string must be split into single characters and fill one row of the array.

```
String str = "hello";
char[][] words = new char[10][5];
words[][] = str.toCharArray();
```

My error is at the 3rd line I don't know how to split the string "hello" into chars and fill only the 1st row of the 2-dimensional array

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: do you get an error? If so what's the exact error reported by the compiler? JFC!

Comment: @Mitsos Dim What is String? Is it std::string?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I think you mixed up languages, `String` (`java.lang.String`) is valid without any imports, while `std::string` would be c++

Answer (score 1):

If you want the array to fill the first row, just asign it to the first row:

```
words[0] = str.toCharArray();
```

Since this will create a new array in the array, you should change the instantiation of `words` to this:

```
char[][] words = new char[5][];
```

Answer (score -1):

Java has a [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class. Make use of it.

Very little is known of what you want with it. But it also has a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) class which I'd recommend as well. For this case, I'd recommend the `ArrayList` implementation.

Now onto the problem at hand, how would this code look now?

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
words.add("hello");
words.add("hello2");
words.add("hello3");
words.add("hello4");
words.add("hello5");

for (String s : words) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

For your case if you are stuck with using arrays.

```
String str="hello";
char[][] words = new char[5][];
words[][] = str.toCharArray();
```

Use something along the line of

```
String str = "hello";
char[][] words = new char[5][];
words[0] = str.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(words[i]);
}
```

However, why invent the wheel again? There are cases however, more can be read on the subject here.

[Array versus List<T>: When to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which)

Comment: `char[][] words = new char[255][5];` - why `char[255]`?

Comment: @msrd0 It was just an example. It can be set to the maximum length of the longest word.

Comment: Why do you set it at all? This is just unnecesary memory usage, remove it as I posted in my solution

Comment: @msrd0 will it even compile without?

Comment: Of course you can create an two-dimensional array and instantiate the one with containing null values

Comment: @msrd0 I just tried it in BlueJ, I was not able to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66367/discussion-between-emz-and-msrd0).

Comment: It does compile without, but notice that you must write `new char[5][]`, not `char[][5]` (sorry, my fault)