# Getting error Type 'System.String' is not supported for deserialization of an array

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm having issues with deserializing a nested array of JSON objects in c# using JavascriptDeserializer

Here is my code

```
  using (Stream s = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
                    {
                        string jsondata = sr.ReadToEnd();

                        var workout = ser.Deserialize<clServiceOutput1>(jsondata);
                    }
                }
```

Here is my Jsondata

```
{"Data":"50951","FileData":[37,80,68,70,45,49,46,51,13,37,226,227,207,211,13,10],"MailItem":null,"Status":"Success","TurnAroundTime":null}
```

Here is my class

```
public class clServiceOutput1
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
        public string FileData { get; set; }
        public string MailItem { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string TurnAroundTime { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileData` is a collection of numeric values in your `json` string.

```
"FileData":[37,80,68,70,45,49,46,51,13,37,226,227,207,211,13,10]
```

You need

```
List<int> FileData //or int[]
```

As a side note, use http://json2csharp.com/ to copy your json and get a C# template class back. Pasting your JSON in the above site results in:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public List<int> FileData { get; set; }
    public object MailItem { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public object TurnAroundTime { get; set; }
}
```

Based on comment from [@xanatos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613130/xanatos)

> By the name of the field, it seems to be the binary "stream" of a
>   file, not something that must be expanded. So a `byte[]` *could also
>   be the type of your field*

Comment: or `"[37,80,68,70,45,49,46,51,13,37,226,227,207,211,13,10]"` :-D

Comment: or even an `int[]` probably

Comment: @xanatos, definitely yes. But I personally prefer `List<int>` over array most of the time. *(based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which))*

Comment: @Habib By the name of the field, it seems to be the binary "stream" of a file, not something that must be expanded. So a `byte[]`

Comment: @xanatos, that is even more probable. I should add that to the answer