# why arrays used at all?

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, html-lists

I heard that linked lists are much better than arrays. **But why are arrays used at all then?**

Comment: Or maybe a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which

Comment: I can't under stand why arrays ?

Comment: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Container/why-array.html

Comment: Why arrays?  1) sometimes you don't need a `Collection` compatible API.  2) sometimes a `Collection` API has too many overheads, 3) a `Collection` API typically has to be implemented on top of a lower level primitive ... like an array.