# Why choose a list over array?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I am working on a project and I noticed that the person used a list for a piece of code. Had it been me, I would have used an array simply out of personal preference because that is what I know. Looking at the code below, what benefit would choosing the list have over the array?

```
List<string> errors = new List<string>();

if (ddDirector.SelectedItem.Value == "") 
   errors.Add("You must select an item in the Director list.");

if (errors.Count > 0)
{
   ErrorList.InnerHtml = "Please correct the following issues below:<br/><ul>";
   foreach (string e in errors)
   {
      ErrorList.InnerHtml += String.Format("<li>{0}</li>", e);
   }
   ErrorList.InnerHtml += "</ul>";
}
return (errors.Count()==0);
```

Comment: A List has methods to easily add and subtract elements at given positions or from the beginning or end as well as a slew of other methods. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Honestly, in my experience, people use `List<T>` because they're lazy and it's easy to use.  It's not always the best choice from a performance perspective though.

Comment: If you are not sure about the number of items, then go for list.

Comment: @CodingGorilla to be fair, you qualified it with "in my experience", but I still feel this is a gross generalisation.

Comment: There's a lot of info on this [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which).

Comment: Eric Lippert's analysis is useful also: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful/

Comment: An aside: Rather than `errors.Count()==0` you can use the [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb337697(v=vs.90).aspx) extension method: `!errors.Any()`

Comment: By the way, if you're writing methods that accept or return lists/arrays you should look for opportunities to use an interface type such as `IList<T>`, `IReadOnlyList<T>`or `ICollection<T>` etc.  Both arrays and lists implement these interfaces so you can achieve a higher level of abstraction by doing so, the concrete type of the collection then becomes an irrelevance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an array, you need to know the size of the collection before it is initialised.

This is not needed for a `List` so it can expand as needed.

As an aside, a `List` has a `Count` property that you can use instead of the `Count()` extension method.

Comment: Arrays have Length, you don't have to use Count()

Comment: @galenus I know, I was referring to the code snippet. Saying that he didnt have to use the extension method there. I wasnt including it as a reason to use List over an array.

Comment: Actually you can use `Enumerable.Count` on arrays and lists. There is no performance difference because the method first checks if the collection can be casted to `ICollection<T>` which is the case for lists and arrays. Then the property is used.

Comment: @David sorry, didn't get your intention

Answer (score 2):

An array have a fixed size. If you do not fill it completely you'll also have to have a variable which stores the number of used slots in the array.

A list usually wraps an array, but takes care of allocating a larger array (if required) and keeping track of the used size.