# Adding an item to a Tuple in C#

Tags: c#, tuples

I have a tuple array as shown below;

```
var games = new Tuple <string, Nullable<double>>[] 
                  { new Tuple<string, Nullable<double>>("Fallout 3:    $", 13.95),
                    new Tuple<string, Nullable<double>>("GTA V:    $", 45.95),
                    new Tuple<string, Nullable<double>>("Rocket League:    $", 19.95) };
```

I am wondering if there is a function would let me add another item to this list.

Please help!

Thanks, Sean

Comment: That's not a list, it's an array, so no.  If you want a list it would be `List<Tuple<string, double?>>`.  And then you can use it's `Add` method.

Comment: that's not a list... it's an array; the only way to add an item would be through creating a new array from the old one with the additional item

Comment: there is also an option to resize the array..

Comment: Thanks for the correction (: (i read somewhere it was a list :/). I need to add another item into the array

Comment: Then make a list instead of an array.

Comment: Why are you using a nullable double - out of interest?

Comment: If the number of elements are going to change at runtime, just don't use an array. Use a list.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

use List

```
var games = new List<Tuple<string, Nullable<double>>>()
    {
        new Tuple<string, Nullable<double>>("Fallout 3:    $", 13.95),
        new Tuple<string, Nullable<double>>("GTA V:    $", 45.95),
        new Tuple<string, Nullable<double>>("Rocket League:    $", 19.95)
    };

games.Add(new Tuple<string, double?>( "Skyrim", 15.10 ));
```

Comment: Awesome, worked! will mark as answer when it lets me (:

Comment: @TechDynasty On a couple of sidenotes the string in the tuple should just be the game name, you can format the spaces and `$` in later; so far there doesn't seem to be much use to be using a  nullable double; the amount should really be a decimal not a double and it would probably be best to use a custom class for this i.e. `Game`

Comment: glad i could help. btw, if your project gets complicated (and it surely will) think of using classes for data instead of Tuples. You'll have cleaner code easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Although the other answers already cover what you should be doing i.e. using a `List` (code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42785571/4631427)):

```
var games = new List<Tuple<string, Nullable<double>>>()
{
    new Tuple<string, Nullable<double>>("Fallout 3:    $", 13.95),
    new Tuple<string, Nullable<double>>("GTA V:    $", 45.95),
    new Tuple<string, Nullable<double>>("Rocket League:    $", 19.95)
};
```

And then you can call the `Add` method:

```
games.Add(new Tuple<string, double?>("Skyrim:    $", 15.10));
```

I'd like to point out a few things you can do to improve your code.

1. The `string` in the `Tuple` should just be the game name, you can always format it later:

   ```
   string formattedGame = $"{game.Item1}:    ${game.Item2}";
   ```
2. There doesn't seem to be much need for using `Nullable<double>` (can also be written as `double?` BTW), consider just using a `double`.
3. When dealing with monetary values it is advisable to use `decimal`, so consider switching to that.
4. Consider using a custom class i.e. `Game`. This will simplify the code and help later on when you want to add more details i.e. `Description`, `Genre`, `AgeRating` etc.

For more detail on when to use an array or a list see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which), however, the short version is you should probably be using a list.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Resize` method:

```
Array.Resize(ref games, games.Length + 1);
games[games.Length - 1] =  new Tuple<string, Nullable<double>>("Star Flare: $", 5.00),;
```

Comment: Needs to be _"Array.Resize(ref games, games.Length + 1);"_

Comment: Although this would work, I would strongly suggest using a `List` in this case

Comment: List is perfect for this scenario. Array.Resize is an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var games = new Tuple<string, Nullable<double>>[] 
              { new Tuple<string, Nullable<double>>("Fallout 3:    $", 13.95),
                new Tuple<string, Nullable<double>>("GTA V:    $", 45.95),
                new Tuple<string, Nullable<double>>("Rocket League:    $", 19.95) };

        Array.Resize(ref games, 4);
        games[3] = new Tuple<string,double?>("Test", 19.95);
    }
}
```