# How to remove multiple elements from an array in java in one iteration?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm new to java and at some points, I had to delete half or some part of an array!

Also, I know we can delete an element by index or looping in an array of integers in java.

However, I would like to know is it possible to delete some part of a sorted array in java in one iteration trying to avoid looping in array? 
let say we have an array of integers like [ 1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 15]

then I want to delete from 7 to 15

OR delete from 1 to 7

can I delete all the elements 7,8,10,15 in one iteration without looping?

if there is one can you show me an example!

thank you so much.

Comment: giving some more context would help you choosing the right way to do it. Are you using integers only? objects? what is the goal of using an array instead of a list?

Comment: yes i'm using only integers !

Comment: i will compare an integer with the middle index in the given sorted array if the number is smaller than the middle index i will need to delete all the elements after the middle index !

Comment: so definitly use a linkedList which doesn't reallocate and copy again all values. I recommend you to add your previous comment as an edit to your question. See my edit

Comment: unfortunately  i cant use link-list it has to be an array ! but like you said using CopyOfRange will reallocate  and copy again all the values !

Comment: could you explain why it has to be an array? dont forget to accept my answer if it helped

Comment: all the other method that using the result of this getting array as input

Comment: list to array is a simple operation toArray if you own business is doing operations that cost more on array than list its more adecuate to create and manipulate a linkedList and then call its toArray function to give it... depending on the context I cannot see... again see doc for toArray function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the [copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) funcion the arrays are structures which need memory allocations for modifications so you can either implement a function which moves the desired items over the undesired ones and then remove the unwanted ones. But it seems a heavy operation for an array.

So you should consider:

- ask yourself if a list is not preferable for what you need as removing various elements is more adecuate from this type of [collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which)
- implement it yourself if the array structure you are using is really the adecuate one with copyOfRange and fill functions

### Edit

As the [javadoc for LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) points out you could do something like

```
myList.removeRange(myList.indexOf(yourSearchedInt), myList.size()) //don't remember in Java if you should use size() - 1...
```

Comment: i guess the best option will be the copyofrange

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "one iteration", since you also talk about looping. But I'm gonna go ahead and assume that you mean that you want to create such a subarray without looping through the array itself. Here is way to achieve that:

```
private Integer[] subarray(Integer[] array, Integer lowestValue, Integer highestValue) {
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(array,
                              Arrays.binarySearch(array, lowestValue),
                              Arrays.binarySearch(array, highestValue) + 1);
}
```

Using this method, this code:

```
Integer[] array = { 1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 15 };

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subarray(array, 1, 7)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subarray(array, 7, 15)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subarray(array, 4, 10)));
```

Will produce:

```
[1, 3, 4, 7]
[7, 8, 10, 15]
[4, 7, 8, 10]
```