Console application requiring input multiple times
I'm attempting to get a more immediate response to the start of my program, this is rough and not a finished product by any means.
When I attempt to enter "Y" or "N" as per the prompt, I have to enter it several times for the console to recognize the input and spit out the appropriate response.
I'd prefer if it only took one input entry to output the respective response. As of right now, this is not the case. I have also attached console output to put into perspective. As you can see, the console wants me to input Y twice, rather than once which is what I intend for it to do (same goes for N).
Code:
internal static class Program
{
   public static void Main()
   {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, Simon!");
        Console.WriteLine("Shall we begin?, Please Enter: Y/N");
    
        Console.ReadLine();
    
        if (Console.ReadLine() == "Y")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Alright, Here we go!");
        }
        else if (Console.ReadLine() == "N")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Adios Simon!");
        }
    }
}

Console:

Hello, Simon! Shall we begin?, Please Enter: Y/N
Y
Y
Alright, Here we go!

I've attempted to rectify my issue with the forementioned code with either using line breaks or additional Console.ReadLine(); code, but nothing has made the mentioned issue disappear, as of right now my input still is required more than once to get a output.
For example:

Y
Y

is required for an response in the console, id like to make it look more like this:

Hello, Simon!
Shall we begin?, Please Enter: Y/N
"Y"
Alright, Here we go!


You should only have a single Console.Readline

A nice reference is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-8.0

The following may be of interest:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74856374/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030908/10024425

Every time you use Console.ReadLine(), you're requesting to read from the console once.
The solution is to have a single Console.ReadLine() and assign it to a variable:
string input = Console.ReadLine();

if (input == "Y")
{
    //...
}
else if (input == "N")
{
    //...
}


Thanks, my dumbass forgot I could do something like this...been a while since i last coded, started this last night

@SimoneQueen if this solves your question, please mark it as accepted answer

well the top answer is pretty good, but to help you a little more, you could use the variable tipe char, which only uses one letter, that would help you better
ex.
 char onlyonecaracter = Console.ReadLine();

if (onlyonecaracter == 'Y') // use single quote for the chart value
{
  //do the thing you want to do 
}
else if (onlyonecaracter == 'N')
{
// do the thing you want to do 
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("Invalid option");
}

as you can see not it also has an option for a wrong input. The char value is good for you since it is more efficient for this case, hope it helps you brother, bless

It seems you're calling readline multiple times as it calls in the if statements. You could try to assign an answer variable to read line and have the if statements that if that answer variable was Y or N.

Caden, Thanks for pointing this out, i see how those extra "readline's" could be an issue. Also, sorry if this is a dumb question, but: How do i go about creating the answer variable? I am still at a beginner stage here. also this isnt the final product, just wanted to get past this hurdle

Sorry for taking so long to respond, school has been busy! I BELIEVE you would do something like:
char answer = Console.ReadLine(); \ Char because you only need one character for Y or N.
