# Get Minimum and Maximum value in a list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using adding two variables in my SetValues list. The variables are Position and Value. Now I want to check in my List what is the maximum Value and what is the minimum Value (For only "Value"). Now when I do the following:

```
[Serializable]
    public struct SetValues {
        public float Position;
        public float Value;
    }

    public List<SetValues> setValues;

void Start () {
        Debug.Log (setValues.Value.Min ());
    }
```

It says that "does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no accessible extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type could be found". The only reason I want to use List is to avoid iteration that should be done when using an array. But what is the mistake am I doing here?

Comment: `var min = setValues.Min(z => z.Value);`

Comment: *"to avoid iteration that should be done when using an array"* - you can't avoid iterations to find min, unless collection is sorted. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/434761/1997232).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at your disposition the IEnumerable extensions provided in the Linq namespace. It is just a simple line of code for min and another one for max

```
var minV = setValues.Min(x => x.Value);
var maxV = setValues.Max(x => x.Value);
```

However, you cannot avoid an iteration over the list. The Min and Max extensions contains an hidden loop that seeks the value requested.

Your code cannot work because *setValues* is a list of **SetValues** objects. It is confusing for us with just a letter different by its case but it is a clear error for the compiler that complains about it. I suggest to find a different name for the class or a different name for the list variable