# Load next level if amount of enemies is zero

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my first time making a 2d game. I'm trying to load a scene if the amount of objects with tag "Enemy" is zero. **Line 22** doesn't seem to work. I don't get any errors.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelLoader : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Animator transition;

    public float transitionTime;

    public GameObject enemyPrefab;
    public GameObject[] enemy;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (enemy == null)
        {
            enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
            Debug.Log("null!");
            LoadNextLevel();
        }
    }

    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadLevel(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1));
    }

    IEnumerator LoadLevel(int levelIndex)
    {
        transition.SetTrigger("Start");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(transitionTime);

        SceneManager.LoadScene(levelIndex);
    }
}
```

```
enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
```

Comment: Don't put the answer in the question. Just post your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially `enemy` is `null`.

So, in the first frame (the first time `Update()` is called) it satisfies the `if` condition and then assign something to `enemy`.

Then, in the second and later frames, `enemy` is not `null` anymore, so it does not satisfies `if (enemy == null)` condition and the lines in the `if` statement does not be executed. It means that, the lines `enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy")` and `LoadNextLevel();` will never be executed after the first frame.

My suggestion is that rewrite the `Update()` just like this:

```
void Update() {
    enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy"); // get "Enemies" first
    // then do something by using it
    if (enemy == null) {
        Debug.Log("null!");
        LoadNextLevel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I solved the question. The problem was that the condition was before assigning the variable.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelLoader : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Animator transition;

    public float transitionTime;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        GameObject[] enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
        if (enemy == null || enemy.Length == 0)
        {
            LoadNextLevel();
        }


        //Debug.Log(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy"));
    }


    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {

        StartCoroutine(LoadLevel(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1));
    }

    IEnumerator LoadLevel(int levelIndex)
    {
        transition.SetTrigger("Start");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(transitionTime);

        SceneManager.LoadScene(levelIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's because the variable enemy is of type array and not a list. Arrays are more difficult to deal with and are of a fixed size.

Instead, consider using a `List`:

```
List<GameObject> enemy = new List<GameObject>();
```

Here are some additional resources to assist you with understanding the difference between arrays and lists.

- https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_arrays.php
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-sharp-list/

**The difference/when to use each**

- [Array versus List<T>: When to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which)
- https://csharp-station.com/c-arrays-vs-lists/
- https://www.educba.com/c-sharp-array-vs-list/

Comment: If the above doesn't work, try `Debug.Log(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");` and see what's printed. If an empty array is printed that means no `GameObject`s with tag eney have been found, and the problem isn't with the code but rather that there's no "Enemy" tagged Game Objects.