# Dynamic array in C#

Tags: c#

Is there any method for creating a dynamic array in C#?

Comment: If you still stuck in the old mud, by using [] instead if List<>, you can use Array.Resize(). Here is a good example. https://www.dotnetperls.com/array-resize

Comment: The link dotnetperls.com/array-resize is not working. (FYI)

Comment: why not use the list?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Take a look at [Generic Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Comment: The question (albeit short and undescriptive) isn't asking about a generic list - Question could be asking about `dynamic[]` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd264736.aspx (array of dynamic types) or `ExpandoObject` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx
I could -1 the answer for not mentioning these

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien, dynamics were introduced in C# 4.0, which was released a full year after this question was originally asked. OP was probably asking about a resizeable data structure like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array

Comment: Answers consisting of only links to articles are unhelpful. There is no guarantee the link will remain active.

Comment: @JamEngulfer That's untrue. If his link text was "Look at this" with "this" linked, I'd agree with you. If you remove the link, and look at what's left, the OP's answer to "take a look at generic lists" is plenty of information to get any future reader googling....

Comment: @LynnCrumbling And yet once again, the answer telling people to google it is the first result for "C# dynamic arrays". Thank god another person replied with a real answer.

Comment: @JamEngulfer For a new programmer, this most definitely answers the question, "how do I make a array dynamic?" Answer: "use a List<T> instead; here's the link to MS docs" (I don't see any ref to Google.)  Lots of upvotes agree. Feel free to downvote, if you haven't yet.

Comment: It doesn't even mention List<T>. It's just a (fragile) link. And *you* said that "take a look at generic lists" is enough information for googling, but googling that just takes you back here. The second answer that gives a code example and explanation instead of lazily linking is far more valuable. And if you wonder why I'm commenting this now, it's because I needed to look it up for reference and encountered the same annoyance as I did three years ago.

Comment: @JamEngulfer "And if you wonder why I'm commenting this now, it's because I needed to look it up for reference and encountered the same annoyance as I did three years ago" -- Ha; fair enough.

Answer (score 100):

Expanding on Chris and Migol`s answer with a code sample.

Using an array

```
Student[] array = new Student[2];
array[0] = new Student("bob");
array[1] = new Student("joe");
```

Using a generic list.  Under the hood the List<T> class uses an array for storage but does so in a fashion that allows it to grow effeciently.

```
List<Student> list = new List<Student>();
list.Add(new Student("bob"));
list.Add(new Student("joe"));
Student joe = list[1];
```

Comment: this example is half-bad, because we both talked about ArrayList

Comment: This answer is better than yours @Migol, because this show how to actually use the List<> instead of just mentioning it as a keyword.
"half-bad" -> "half-good" -> good

Answer (score 70):

Sometimes plain arrays are preferred to Generic Lists, since they are more convenient (Better performance for costly computation -Numerical Algebra Applications for example, or for exchanging Data with Statistics software like R or Matlab)

In this case you may use the ToArray() method after initiating your List dynamically

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("one");
list.Add("two");
list.Add("three");

string[] array = list.ToArray();
```

Of course, this has sense only if the size of the array is never known nor fixed *ex-ante*.
if you already know the size of your array *at some point of the program* it is better to initiate it as a fixed length array. (If you retrieve data from a ResultSet for example, you could count its size and initiate an array of that size, dynamically)

Comment: Not worth it, as long as you'are using indexer.

Comment: Ararys aren't more convenient (they offer subset of List<T> interface) and offer almost the same performance, since List<T> uses regular array underneath.

Iteration for 6000000 elements:

  List/for: 1971ms 
  Array/for: 1864ms 

  ( Benchmark from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454916/performance-of-arrays-vs-lists )

Comment: If you *have* to pass an array to an interface then it *must* be an array. It's much easier to build a list and then make it into an array just before you pass it. I like this answer more than the others because it addresses the question!

Comment: Creating an array dynamically is not the same as creating a dynamic array.

Answer (score 37):

`List<T>` for strongly typed one, or `ArrayList` if you have .NET 1.1 or love to cast variables.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with dynamic objects:

```
var dynamicKeyValueArray = new[] { new {Key = "K1", Value = 10}, new {Key = "K2", Value = 5} };

foreach(var keyvalue in dynamicKeyValueArray)
{
    Console.Log(keyvalue.Key);
    Console.Log(keyvalue.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the **array list** which is actually implement array. It takes initially array of size 4 and when it gets full, a new array is created with its double size and the data of first array get copied into second array, now the new item is inserted into new array. 
Also the name of second array creates an alias of first so that it can be accessed by the same name as previous and the first array gets disposed

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Array Example:

```
Console.WriteLine("Define Array Size? ");
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers:\n");
int[] arr = new int[number];

for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++ )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Array Index: "+i + " AND Array Item: " + arr[i].ToString());
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: There is nothing dynamic about the array in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use arraylist object from collections class

```
using System.Collections;

static void Main()
{
  ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
}
```

when you want to add elements you can use

```
arr.Add();
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer seems to be the answer you are looking for [Why can't I do this: dynamic x = new ExpandoObject { Foo = 12, Bar = "twelve" }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478048/why-cant-i-do-this-dynamic-x-new-expandoobject-foo-12-bar-twelve)

Read about the `ExpandoObject` here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx

And the `dynamic` type here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd264736.aspx