# C# Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have the following piece of code that is suppose to extract some info from a file.

```
private string[][] users;
private string userID;

public void getInfo()
{

    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"U:\Final Projects\Bank\ATM\db.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++ )
    {
        string[] values = lines[i].Split(',');
        for (int b = 0; b < 5; b++ )
        {

            users[i][b] = values[b];

        }


    }
}
```

the line `users[i][b] = values[b];` returns the error : " Object reference not set to an instance of an object. " but I am not sure why. the code is suppose to read each line and split the line by `,` and create 2 dimensional array from the info.

Comment: Seems like a homework, anyway, try initializing users variable

Comment: What is the value of i and b when the exception is thrown? Either users[i][b] or values[b] is causing the exception -- can you tell which one?

Comment: @Munim its a final project, but I am not asking you to do it for me :) just need help with, is that against the rules?

Comment: @Keith its value `b` and the value is 0 when the error appears

Comment: The `users` array doesn't appear to be initialized.

Comment: See [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to allocate space for the array

```
string[,] users = new string[M,N];
```

Comment: is that the way you create a 2 dimensional array in C#?? because I was under the impression that its `string[][] users`

Comment: That just declares the array you need to use new before you can [dereference it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: do i need to specify `M` and `N`?? is it not possible to have it dynamically grow as I add new values??

Comment: If sizes are not known you can use `List< List<string> >`

Comment: See this question for info on creating dynamic arrays: [Dynamic array in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594853/dynamic-array-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's code you've not shown us, you never actually created the array. Therefore, `users` will be `null`, so attempt to dereference it doesn't make sense. Hence, the exception.

Comment: oh sorry the method is part of a class, so I call it in the start of the program to gather the data

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate `users`:

```
string[][] users = new string[n][];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    users[i] = new string[m];
}
```

`n` and `m` can be variables.