# C# adding unknown number of values into an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to add multiple values into an array, but I want to stop when I feel like it.

Here is the condition I added

```
while (numbers[i] != 10)
{
    i++;
    numbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
}
```

It will stop when the value entered is 10. But I want it to stop when I just press ENTER.

How do I do this?

Comment: use resiziable collection - `List<int>`

Comment: The answer is to use a collection as turbanoff said. Take a look at a topic that is the same as yours [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594853/dynamic-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @O.D So what? I'm even below that.

Comment: @CodesInChaos its nothing i would be proud of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking about how to detect the "just press ENTER" condition:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input == "") {
    break;
}

numbers[i] = int.Parse(input);
// etc
```

Comment: Sry, had to wait 5 mins until i could accept it and had to leave.

Answer (score 3):

```
var numbers = new List<int>();
string s;
while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s = Console.ReadLine())) {
    numbers.Add(int.Parse(s));
}
```

Comment: Depending on what error behavior is desired, it might also be a good idea to replace `int.Parse` with `int.TryParse`.

Comment: you can convert it to an array if thats what you really need: ` int[] array = numbers.ToArray();`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for some way to re-size the array, you can use [Array.Resize](http://coderbuddy.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/dynamic-arrays/)

Comment: This doesn't actually resize the array. It creates a new array with the desired size, and copies over the existing elements.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `numbers` like this.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
```

Then modify the loop as such.

```
while (numbers[i] != 10)
{
    i++;

    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) { break; }

    numbers.Add(int.Parse(input));
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);  
}
```

Comment: You only answered half the question. You totally missed the stop when the input is empty part.