# Add Value to Array Without Specifying A Key C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Like in PHP and some other languages, is there a way to add a value to an array without specifying the index?

```
int[] aWhich = {};

aWhich[] = 1;
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you want features like that, why even use an array instead of a comfy collection, like `List<int>`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594853/dynamic-array-in-c-sharp

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus You should never be using an `ArrayList` outside of old legacy apps.  You should be using `List`.

Comment: If you could describe your scenario a little more, maybe we could give you a good anwser. Like this, the answer is just no.

Comment: @Servy You are right, of course. Got my languages mixed up again.

Comment: Please don't use ArrayList use List<T> instead.  You'll have an overhead from boxing if you use an ArrayList with any value types such as your `int`s.

Comment: What do you expect that code to do Gabriel.  Do you want it to add it to the end of the collection, the start, do you want an unordered set of items in this collection, or what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not to an `Array` or any other type since the [indexer operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) must have at least one parameter (through it does not have to be an `int`).

You can add to the end of a `List`, though:

```
List<int> aWhich = new List<int>();

aWhich.Add(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to specify the maximum number of values that the array can hold:

```
int[] MyArray = new int[14];
```

Here 14 is the maximum number of values that **MyArray** can hold.

```
int value = 0;
void MyFuntion(){
       MyArray[value] = 1;
       value++;
}
```

In this way you can add values without specifying index number it will automatically put the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Arrays in C# (and .NET) are immutable (in terms of their size, not necessarely their content) and you access their values by the index. What's you are looking for is a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) or something that might suits your need better in the [System.Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.aspx) or [System.Collections.Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx) namespaces.

Comment: Nobody is looking for an ArrayList, ever.

Comment: @user7116 I agree, but it's still an option. Easier to understand than genericity from a beginner perspective.

Comment: We call that, "setting them up for failure."

Answer (score 0):

There is one other way, Fist add elements to a List, then convert it into array.

Eg:

```
var intList = new List<int>();
intList.Add(1);
intList.Add(2);

var intArray = intList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this method does NOT work for adding a new array item.

```
myArray[myArray.Length] = newArrayItem;
```

`.Length - #` will work for *overwriting* array items.

Comment: this can't work. If you specify array of 5 elements then it will try to add new item to the 5th place and you will get exception.

Comment: @knil4_crack I'm by no means an experienced C# programmer, but I'm fairly sure I used this technique successfully in a previous project. Although I don't remember in what context. Maybe it works, just not in the way I described? Or I'm just wrong.

Comment: is this what you mean? Give it a shot https://dotnetfiddle.net/zAJcm0

Comment: @knil4_crack I can't find the use of Length in my most recent C# project. I might have switched to using a list instead of an array, I can't remember why, but it seems you're right.