# C# arrays, how to create empty array?

Tags: c#, php, arrays

I'm learning c#, with my primary language before now being php. I was wondering how (or if) you could create an empty array in c#.

In php, you can create an array, and then add any number of entries to it.

```
$multiples=array();
$multiples[] = 1;
$multiples[] = 2;
$multiples[] = 3;
```

In c#, I'm having trouble doing something similar:

```
int[] arraynums = new int[];
arraynums[] = 1;
arraynums[] = 2;
arraynums[] = 3;
```

Which gives the error "array creation must have array size or array initializer." If I don't know how many entries I want to make, how do I do this? Is there a way around this?

Comment: Arrays have a static size, use a list

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that C# as most programing languages doesn't allow to create arrays with dinamic size.

Comment: In PHP arrays are more like dictionaries in C#, they are not real old school arrays, but a dynamic object instead. On the other hand, C# arrays are static closer to what they used to be in C and C++. To mimic PHP's array use a list or a dictionary instead. [It seems to me a bit sad that PHP is teaching that arrays bend and twist]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know the size in advance, use a `List<T>` instead of an array.  An array, in C#, is a fixed size, and you must specify the size when creating it.

```
var arrayNums = new List<int>();
arrayNums.Add(1);
arrayNums.Add(2);
```

Once you've added items, you can extract them by index, just like you would with an array:

```
int secondNumber = arrayNums[1];
```

Comment: In what situations would arrays be superior (I'm googling now, real quick)?

Comment: @JamesG. They're used much more rarely in C#.  They're useful if you know, in advance, how many items you will have, and you know that it will never change.  Otherwise, use a `List<T>` or other collection type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which Yep, that would be the largest difference I've found, so far.

Answer (score 2):

c# arrays have a static size.

```
int[] arraynums = new int[3];
```

or

```
int[] arraynums = {1, 2, 3}
```

if you want to use dynamic sized array, you should use ArrayList, or List.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a different collection such as a `List<T>` or a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Calling the collection in PHP an array is just a misnomer. An array is a continuous fixed size block of memory that contains only a single type and offers direct access by calculating the offset for a given index. The data type in PHP does none of these things.

Examples;

```
List<int> my_ints = new List<int>();
my_ints.Add(500);


Dictionary<string, int> ids = new Dictionary<string, int>();
ids.Add("Evan", 1);

int evansId = ids["Evan"];
```

Examples of when to use an array;

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(myPath);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    // i perform better than other collections here!
```

Answer (score 1):

Newer way, since .NET 4.6 / Core 1.0, in case somebody hits this:

`System.Array.Empty<T>()` method.

This is more efficient if called multiple times, as it's backed by a single static readonly array generated at compile time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.empty
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,3079

Answer (score 0):

Try this post: [Dynamic array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594853/dynamic-array-in-c-sharp).  It has a couple of links in the first answer that show alternate ways of  indexing data.  In C#, there is no way of making dynamic arrays but those links show some workarounds.