# Google Pie Chart Array Values

Tags: javascript, asp.net, multidimensional-array, google-visualization, pygooglechart

i am having this code `

```
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

      var  abc = [
            ['Language', 'Speakers'],
            ['German', 5.85],
            ['French', 1.66],
          ['Italian', 0.316],
          ['Romansh', 0.0791]
        ];
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(abc);

        var options = {
            legend: 'none',
            pieSliceText: 'label',
            title: 'Swiss Language Use (100 degree rotation)',
            pieStartAngle: 100,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>`
```

Now i want to add Dynamic Values From Database or From Server side this is not issue..
issue is howto make "abc" array dynamic

Advance Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic array in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594853/dynamic-array-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `hidden fields` to get value from server side on `pageload`

```js
var Present = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%= Present.ClientID%>').value);
            var absent = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%= Absent.ClientID%>').value);
            var NBH = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%= NBH.ClientID%>').value);
            var NDS = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%= NDS.ClientID%>').value);
            var Delay = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%= Delay.ClientID%>').value);
            var Training = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%= Training.ClientID%>').value);
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
              ['Present', Present],
              ['Absent', absent],
              ['NBH', NBH],
              ['NDS', NDS],
              ['Delay', Delay],
              ['Training', Training]
            ]);
```

```html
<asp:HiddenField ID="Present" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="Absent" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="NBH" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="NDS" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="Delay" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="Training" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

One data structure would be using a `List<List<string>>` and then serialize it.

```
List<List<string>> lists = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>{"Language", "Speakers"},
    new List<string>{"German", "5.85"},
    new List<string>{"French", "1.66"},
    new List<string>{"Italian", "0.316"},
    new List<string>{"Romansh", "0.170"}
};
var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(lists);
```

The output will be

```
[["Language","Speakers"],["German","5.85"],["French","1.66"],["Italian","0.316"],["Romansh","0.170"]]
```

This will be starting point for your query.