# Dynamic array, index was outside the bound of the array?

Tags: c#

Here's my code:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    
    private static string[] ar = new string[] {};
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        ar[0] = "hello";
        
        Console.WriteLine("Total array length: " + ar.Length);
        
    }
}
```

It show the error below when I run the above code:

```
Run-time exception (line 10): Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

I thought that's how to define a dynamic array in C# but I must be missed something here.

Comment: @PeterTrencansky How?

Comment: I still haven't found the answer.  My intention is to create a dynamic array and later access to that array by using its index.  I did try using the List but got an out of range error.

Comment: I guess this is a limitation in C#.  As a language, it should have a dynamic array and allow access to its values by reference its index. Same when adding a value to an array, you should be able to add a value to an array by using reference the next index in the array.  List is not deliver this requirement.

Comment: @fin Maybe you are looking for `IDictionary<>` instances. You can directly set and read any index in an `IDictionary<>` instance.

Comment: @fin A dynamic array in C# is a `List<T>` that under the covers contains an array that it resizes as needed.

Comment: thanks @Progman - yes, Dictionary is what I'm looking for.  It does what I expected.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You create an empty array, that is an array with fixed length `0` and no entries.

Consider `List<string> ar = new List<string>()` instead.

Related thread: [Dynamic array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594853/)

---

**EDIT:** It later turned out the asker could use a `Dictionary<int, string>`. For a `Dictionary<,>`, the `set` accessor of the indexer (by which I mean the syntax `ar[0] = "hello"`) will either create a new key/value pair (`0` → `"hello"`), or overwrite the value of an already existing key (`0`).

Answer (score 1):

Declaring `private static string[] ar = new string[] {}` actually means that you have an array of string with size of 0, i.e., empty array. C# doesn't allow to resize an array so you should initialize the array size if the length is fixed and this the reason you are getting the error `Index was outside the bounds of the array`. you are trying to set a value to an index which is larger then the array length.

In case the length is not fixed and you want to be dynamic, I recommend using `List`. Lists use arrays to store the data so you get the speed benefit of arrays with the convenience of a LinkedList by being able to add and remove items without worrying about having to manually change its size.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("hello");
myList.Add("Ola");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static string[] ar = new string[] {};
```

The above will create an empty array of string (i.e. allowed length = 0) and hence the IndexOutOfBound exception.

When you are not certain of the size of your collection, use **List**.
For e.g.: -

```
List<string> ar= new List<string>();
ar.Add("hello");
ar.Add("Ola");
```