# More elegant way to increase an int-array?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I got an int-array with multiple values. I have to add an element to that array. I would solve it that way:

```
int[] myIntArray=SomeMagicThere();

List<int> intList= myIntArray.ToList();
intList.Add(88);
myIntArray= intList.ToArray();
```

(This is quite simplified, there are good reasons why I cannot change the type of myIntArray)

Would you solve it in another way? It feels a bit "dirty" to do two casts

Comment: What's the reason for needing it in an array in the first place?

Comment: Why not use a List<int> in the first place? Does it really have to be an array?

Comment: As I wrote: This is a simplyfied example. I am accessing an existing object-structure created from an entity framework. No good idea to change it just for that purpose :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The canonical way would be

```
Array.Resize(ref myIntArray, myIntArray.Length + 1);
myIntArray[myIntArray.Length - 1] = 88;
```

<strike>A LINQ version that doesn't perform quite so many array copies as yours would be</strike>

```
myIntArray = myIntArray.Concat(new[] { 88 }).ToArray();
```

**EDIT**: This LINQ version is actually slower than your original! LINQ array-to-list and list-to-array is optimized to a direct array copy, whereas the `Concat` means LINQ no longer knows how long the sequence is and thus results in multiple array resizes and copies as the internal buffer's capacity is reached.

(I'm assuming you *have* to use an array, as you seem familiar with lists already.)

Comment: I really like the LINQ-approach, even if it just looks better :). Thanks

Comment: @Ole Just so you know, the LINQ version is about ten times slower than the `Array` version. In fact, it's slower than your original, and now I'm going to have to find out why. Probably LINQ list-to-array and array-to-list has some nice optimization, whereas `Concat` results in a genuine, slow iterator loop being set up.

Answer (score 2):

> Would you solve it in another way?

I'd change `SomeMagicThere` (of course, if it is possible):

```
public List<int> SomeMagicThere()
{
   // ...
}
```

There should not be any performance lag, because internally `List<T>` uses array to store its items. In fact, it does array resizing for you, and I can't see any reason to write the same code, that `List<T>` already has.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options:

1. If you change the size frequently - consider using List< int> instead of Array.
2. Use Array.Resize static method.

Arrays are fast for accessing elements by index, while List<> is fast for adding/removing elements.

Comment: i'm pretty sure that List is as fast when it comes to accessing by index

Comment: Not as fast as array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454916/performance-of-arrays-vs-lists

Answer (score 0):

The offending line is the first:

> ```
> int[] myIntArray=SomeMagicThere();
> ```

Change to:

```
List<int> magicInts = new List<int>(SomeMagicThere());
```

Then you can easily call:

```
magicInts.Add(88);
```

The [`List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) will copy the input into itself, allowing you to easily add and remove items without ever having to modify the array yourself.