# Most efficient type of array to iterate through

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a "character" and the character have an array (or list, or dictinary) of "effects" applied to them. Each "effect" is a struct that changes certain parameters. What is the most efficient type of array to use in this case, and what is the best way to iterate through them if that may have to be used quite often.

EDIT: 
it goes something like this

```
public class hero { int level; public int moveSpeed; Dictionary<effect> = effects;

int GetSpeed (){
    int m = movespeed;
    foreach (effect in effects) {
        if (type = "movement")
            m += effect.value;
    }
    return m;
    }
}

public struct effect {string type; int value;}

public static void Main (string args) {
    hero Baragorn = new hero();
    Baragorn.speed = 10;

    effect swamp = new effect();
    swamp.type = "movement";
    swamp.value = -3;

    Baragorn.effects.add(swamp)

    printf(Baragorn.GetSpeed().ToString());
}
```

Comment: Don't talk about your code, show it ;-)

Comment: Well, afaik, `for` loops perform slightly better when looping through lists. If that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Would you recommend using list over a dictionary? or array?

Comment: [Premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization) FTW!

Comment: @uteist `for` loops perform better than `foreach`, but no matter wether you use a `Effect[]` or `List<Effect>`.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I didn't mean lists as in `List`s tbh :) Meant "Collections" in general.

Comment: This link might help: [Selecting a Collection Class (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc79sx1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @uteist I understood this, I just wanted to add this to make sure the OP understands this, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the difference in performance iterating and array with a for or a foreach see: http://www.dotnetperls.com/for-foreach

Or check: [Performance of Arrays vs. Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454916/performance-of-arrays-vs-lists)

The answer compares arrays and lists with for and foreach.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to use a `Dictionary` when you have to iterate anyway. `Dictionary` is fast when you know the key you want to access already. They have no advantage over a `List<Effect>` or `Effect[]`.

`List<Effect>` will be better if you have to often add/remove effects. You can not add/remove from an array easily, but you can do so with a `List`.

`Effect[]` will be better if the list of effects is constant or doesn't change very often. Adding/removing from an array is expensive, as the entire array needs to be copied, but if you don't do that often, `Effect[]` will be the right data structure.

Performance measures show that using `for` to iterate a list/array is faster than using `foreach`.

Comment: Yea, i simplified it for an example, the idea is to key it through enumerator so i can remove effects without iteration.