# Which is tidier to sort, an arraylist or an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, arraylist

Not a problem, just a curiosity.

Which is tidier according to you, use an array list and sort through it?
Or an array with if statement to store and sort the values?

The sorting is for if user enters 32541 and i want them sorted out as 12345.

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` anymore, use a `List<T>`.

Comment: @TheGeneral I wondered when you'd show up to upvote it for this reason ;) last week I decided to change my coding evaluation heuristics towards more code-cuteness ;) now I count the time until the first of my fellow developers smashes a keyboard into my face...

Comment: Get a room guys :P

Answer (score 0):

Sorting values from an array will always be faster than a List .

Please refer to this post : [Performance of Arrays vs. Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454916/performance-of-arrays-vs-lists)

Comment: Just to say, an Array is an IEnumerable too

Answer (score 0):

If the number of elements is going to change use a `List`, if it is fixed use an `Array`.

That's all you have to think about.