# Is there performance issue with list.ForEach() in .NET 7?

Tags: c#, performance, foreach, .net-7.0

After switching a personnal solution from .NET 6 to .NET 7, time to read large amount of data go from 18s to 4min 30s (approximately).

Before starting to develop it, I have a test function allowing me to have the critical path without big bottlenecks.

```c
private void SpeedTest()
{
    int nbdata = 6000000;
    List<int> list = new(nbdata);
    var rnd = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
    Random rand = new(12345);
    for (int i = 0; i < nbdata; i++)
    {
        var rnddata = new byte[sizeof(int)];
        rnd.GetBytes(rnddata);
        list.Add(BitConverter.ToInt32(rnddata));
    }
    int[] arr = list.ToArray();

    //Begin test
    int chk = 0;
    Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 100; rpt++)
    {
        int len = list.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            chk += list[i];
        }
    }
    watch.Stop();
    SpeedText.Text += string.Format("List/for Count out: {0}ms ({1})", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, chk) + Environment.NewLine;

    chk = 0;
    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 100; rpt++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            chk += list[i];
        }
    }
    watch.Stop();
    SpeedText.Text += string.Format("List/for Count in: {0}ms ({1})", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, chk) + Environment.NewLine;

    chk = 0;
    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 100; rpt++)
    {
        int len = arr.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            chk += arr[i];
        }
    }
    watch.Stop();
    SpeedText.Text += string.Format("Array/for Count out: {0}ms ({1})", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, chk) + Environment.NewLine;

    chk = 0;
    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 100; rpt++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            chk += arr[i];
        }
    }
    watch.Stop();
    SpeedText.Text += string.Format("Array/for Count in: {0}ms ({1})", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, chk) + Environment.NewLine;

    chk = 0;
    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 100; rpt++)
    {
        int k = list.Count;
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            chk += list[j];
        }
    }
    watch.Stop();
    SpeedText.Text += string.Format("List/for: {0}ms ({1})", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, chk) + Environment.NewLine;

    chk = 0;
    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 100; rpt++)
    {
        foreach (int i in list)
        {
            chk += i;
        }
    }
    watch.Stop();
    SpeedText.Text += string.Format("List/foreach: {0}ms ({1})", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, chk) + Environment.NewLine;

    chk = 0;
    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 100; rpt++)
    {
        list.ForEach(i => chk += i);
    }
    watch.Stop();
    SpeedText.Text += string.Format("List/foreach function: {0}ms ({1})", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, chk) + Environment.NewLine;

    chk = 0;
    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 100; rpt++)
    {
        int k = arr.Length;
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            chk += arr[j];
        }
    }
    watch.Stop();
    SpeedText.Text += string.Format("Array/for: {0}ms ({1})", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, chk) + Environment.NewLine;

    chk = 0;
    watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int rpt = 0; rpt < 100; rpt++)
    {
        foreach (int i in arr)
        {
            chk += i;
        }
    }
    watch.Stop();
    SpeedText.Text += string.Format("Array/foreach: {0}ms ({1})", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, chk) + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Result .NET 6:

```c
List/for Count out: 1442ms (398007896)
List/for Count in: 1446ms (398007896)
Array/for Count out: 1256ms (398007896)
Array/for Count in: 1254ms (398007896)
List/for: 1435ms (398007896)
List/foreach: 1258ms (398007896)
List/foreach function: 1452ms (398007896) <=
Array/for: 1255ms (398007896)
Array/foreach: 1254ms (398007896)
```

Result .NET 7:

```c
List/for Count out: 1483ms (272044760)
List/for Count in: 1489ms (272044760)
Array/for Count out: 1255ms (272044760)
Array/for Count in: 1263ms (272044760)
List/for: 1482ms (272044760)
List/foreach: 1873ms (272044760)
List/foreach function: 7997ms (272044760) <=
Array/for: 1254ms (272044760)
Array/foreach: 1255ms (272044760)
```

Code behind this issue:

```c
list.ForEach(i => chk += i);
```

Is this problem inside .NET 7?

Do I have any hope of finding solution without having to change all calls to this function?

I use many other functions that perform better in .NET 7 than in .NET 6.
I wish I could stay on this version.

What do you recommend?

Thanks.

## EDIT:

I used ForEach few times to reading code. Initially in .NET 6, the time loss was acceptable. I used Tuple with data read in large files.

Example:

```c
listValue.ForEach(x => process((new col(x.name, position++, startId++, x.refState, x.refPosition, x.refTable, x.withoutRef, x.deleted, x.resetData), option)));
```

```c
foreach((string name, uint refState, uint refPosition, uint refTable, bool withoutRef, bool deleted, bool resetData)x in listValue)
{
    process((new col(x.name, position++, startId++, x.refState, x.refPosition, x.refTable, x.withoutRef, x.deleted, x.resetData), option))
};
```

My software is far from being finished and I use public data files to test it:

- xlsx file with 1,000,000 rows by 14 columns
- csv file with 10,000,000 rows by 14 columns

I made some changes in my code between switching to .NET6 and .NET 7 and saw the times increase dramatically on my 1st test in .NET 7.
So I went back to my original benchmark code to see if there were any changes before revising my entire code.

I think processing time and code of this benchmark is suitable to make a decision in my case. I just want to see how long the user will have to wait. So I put myself in the same case as user. Benchmark with List of 5000 elements is not relevant. I work with large List and performance can be affected by this size.

This test is basic and reveals a big difference between .NET 6 and .NET 7 with same code.
[Performance of Arrays vs. Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454916/performance-of-arrays-vs-lists)

Here issue is not how measurement is made but the result.
There is no library used that could have differents versions and that could influence the result.

I test on Windows 10 with Ryzen 1700 and RAM 16Gb.

## EDIT2:

Project to test:
https://github.com/gandf/TestPerfForEach

Clean & generate project and run outside Visual Studio.

Result .NET 6:

```c
Test with 6000000 NbData
List/foreach: 1254ms (2107749308)
List/foreach function: 1295ms (2107749308)
Test with 6000000 NbData
List/foreach: 1259ms (1107007452)
List/foreach function: 1255ms (1107007452)
Test with 6000000 NbData
List/foreach: 1253ms (745733412)
List/foreach function: 1256ms (745733412)
Test with 6000000 NbData
List/foreach: 1253ms (-280872836)
List/foreach function: 1259ms (-280872836)
```

Result .NET 7:

```c
Test with 6000000 NbData
List/foreach: 1866ms (-998431744)
List/foreach function: 8347ms (-998431744)
Test with 6000000 NbData
List/foreach: 1753ms (715062008)
List/foreach function: 1368ms (715062008)
Test with 6000000 NbData
List/foreach: 1754ms (667927108)
List/foreach function: 1335ms (667927108)
Test with 6000000 NbData
List/foreach: 1749ms (310491380)
List/foreach function: 1366ms (310491380)
```

Same condition and tests run several times:

1. .NET 6 faster.
2. Issue with `list.ForEach` only first run. After quicker than `foreach`.

Comment: ...why are you using `.ForEach` instead of `foreach`? Using `.ForEach` will always be slower because you're creating a closure, which means `chk` has to be heap-allocated (which is bad) and you'll likely lose out on temporal locality (which is also bad).

Comment: FYI there is a better way to measure such performance: https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: @Dai I used ForEach a few times because of my previous benchmark on .NET 6 (acceptable loss of performance) with because it simplified reading code. Here it's a benchmark used to make a decision: Which code to use according to needs and performance. A work with list of Tuple. I will complete my question.

Comment: *`foreach((string name, uint refState, uint refPosition, uint refTable, bool withoutRef, bool deleted, bool resetData)x in listValue)`* -- Why not simply `foreach(var x in listValue)` instead?

Comment: I don't like this formulation for maintenance.

Comment: You mean that you don't like the `var` because the type is implicit? If so, why don't you specify explicitly the type of the argument in the `ForEach` lambda too?  `listValue.ForEach((LooongType x) =>`

Comment: It looks like your code is bad overall. And yes, the testing framework can produce different results depending on many variables, so your testing code is useless as well, you. didn't even mention how the code is compiled. Please don't jump to conclusions and run a proper preference profiler on your code.

Comment: @HansPassant Good video. This explains why results are less good in .NET 7. But this does not explain why first launch of `ForEach` is x6 slow and why after it's faster than `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found source of this issue.
One year ago, I see this : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-6/

I left in PATH 2 options:

- DOTNET_ReadyToRun 0
- DOTNET_TieredPGO  1

With these parameters, I had noticed a very slight degradation of the first call in .NET 6 with an improvement with others calls.
So I kept it because the impact was negligible.

So there is a case where the first call takes x6 more time in .NET7 with these options.

I just deleted them. Results after reboot:

.NET 6

```
Test with 6000000 NbData
List/foreach: 1263ms (-1425648688)
List/foreach function: 1312ms (-1425648688)
Test with 6000000 NbData
List/foreach: 1253ms (-1169873892)
List/foreach function: 1256ms (-1169873892)
Test with 6000000 NbData
List/foreach: 1257ms (1528933740)
List/foreach function: 1256ms (1528933740)
Test with 6000000 NbData
List/foreach: 1254ms (-1327641484)
List/foreach function: 1254ms (-1327641484)
```

.NET 7

```
Test with 6000000 NbData
List/foreach: 1470ms (991593448)
List/foreach function: 1411ms (991593448)
Test with 6000000 NbData
List/foreach: 1465ms (751941656)
List/foreach function: 1434ms (751941656)
Test with 6000000 NbData
List/foreach: 1470ms (-17227852)
List/foreach function: 1435ms (-17227852)
Test with 6000000 NbData
List/foreach: 1469ms (1422420324)
List/foreach function: 1437ms (1422420324)
```

It's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `BenchmarkDotNet`, I tried re-creating your scenario and then ran it against both .NET6 and .NET7.

I used smaller numbers because the benchmarking tool can take a minute.

Here's the code I used:

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Order;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Experiments
{
    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    [Orderer(SummaryOrderPolicy.FastestToSlowest)]
    [RankColumn]
    //[SimpleJob(BenchmarkDotNet.Jobs.RuntimeMoniker.Net70)]
    public class ForEachBenchmark
    {
        [Params(100, 1_000)]
        public int N;

        [Params(5_000)]
        public int NbData;

        private int[] arr = Array.Empty<int>();
        private List<int> list = new List<int>();

        [GlobalSetup]
        public void Setup()
        {
            arr = new int[NbData];

            var rnd = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();

            for (int i = 0; i < NbData; i++)
            {
                var rnddata = new byte[sizeof(int)];
                rnd.GetBytes(rnddata);
                arr[i] = BitConverter.ToInt32(rnddata);
            }

            list = new List<int>(arr[..N]);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void ForLoop()
        {
            int chk = 0;
            for (int rpt = 0; rpt < N; rpt++)
            {
                chk += arr[rpt];
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void ForEachLoop()
        {
            int chk = 0;
            foreach (var rpt in arr[..N])
            {
                chk += rpt;
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void ListForEachLoop()
        {
            int chk = 0;
            list.ForEach(l => chk += l);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `Program.cs` on my console app:

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

BenchmarkRunner.Run<ForEachBenchmark>();
```

Here are my results:

.NET 6

| Method | N | NbData | Mean | Error | StdDev | Rank | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ForLoop | 100 | 5000 | 57.02 ns | 0.583 ns | 0.517 ns | 1 | - | - |
| ForEachLoop | 100 | 5000 | 118.96 ns | 2.404 ns | 3.290 ns | 2 | 0.1013 | 424 B |
| ListForEachLoop | 100 | 5000 | 275.77 ns | 5.468 ns | 7.300 ns | 3 | 0.0210 | 88 B |
| ForLoop | 1000 | 5000 | 611.56 ns | 9.434 ns | 9.266 ns | 4 | - | - |
| ForEachLoop | 1000 | 5000 | 1,235.28 ns | 30.499 ns | 88.968 ns | 5 | 0.9613 | 4024 B |
| ListForEachLoop | 1000 | 5000 | 2,478.17 ns | 88.920 ns | 249.342 ns | 6 | 0.0191 | 88 B |

.NET 7

| Method | N | NbData | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Rank | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ForLoop | 100 | 5000 | 55.41 ns | 0.907 ns | 1.080 ns | 55.22 ns | 1 | - | - |
| ForEachLoop | 100 | 5000 | 90.06 ns | 2.250 ns | 6.455 ns | 86.91 ns | 2 | 0.1013 | 424 B |
| ListForEachLoop | 100 | 5000 | 310.84 ns | 6.278 ns | 15.399 ns | 305.42 ns | 3 | 0.0210 | 88 B |
| ForLoop | 1000 | 5000 | 510.95 ns | 10.273 ns | 17.720 ns | 511.14 ns | 4 | - | - |
| ForEachLoop | 1000 | 5000 | 792.89 ns | 27.420 ns | 80.849 ns | 789.39 ns | 5 | 0.9613 | 4024 B |
| ListForEachLoop | 1000 | 5000 | 2,527.76 ns | 58.979 ns | 168.271 ns | 2,498.65 ns | 6 | 0.0191 | 88 B |

To your point, the List `ForEach` does appear to have slowed down a bit between the two versions.
Those numbers are in NANOseconds, so the change is pretty small (~50 ns).
The other numbers all seem to have improved between versions. Memory allocation held steady.

Comment: The OP has asked for a `List<int>`. Why are you `foreach`ing an array instead?

Comment: You must add libraries and you test on small data. `List<5000>` dont show same performance than `List<6000000>`.

Comment: @FlorentH. If you think the array size is the issue just changed the variable to 10000000 and run it. A list sort of an array under the hood and size can make it get allocated to the large object heap, but the list ForEach is a for loop that does some extra checks so the only overhead is delegate invocation not the loop part.

Comment: @FlorentH. You can change the size of the test using the fields provided. I think maybe my point was missed by you and some commenters. I didn't post my answer to demonstrate that you can create easy-to-read apple-to-apple comparison of competing ideas using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) (no affiliation) - but rather to lend more evidence that your assertion was correct.

Comment: @VicF In my question, I use Array only to have a reference other than List. This question is not List vs Array. I manage a lot of data but I don't now before read all data how many size I must get. It seems to me that arrays are continuous memory sets. This could cause problems with large data sets. I think with List, I don't have this kind of problem but the data can be scattered in RAM.

Comment: @VicF I tested your method and I get the same results as you. .NET 6 seems to be faster in this test even when using lists and even when using a larger data set. But in practice this is not what happens. When user launches process, loop used run only once. Your test only shows averages. In practice it is the 1st run that is used. I have edited the question (look at EDIT2) which shows this behaviour.

Comment: @FlorentH. Okay. You can change it to only run once on each test iteration. You can randomize the test any way you want. I never thought the question was about list vs array. It's about performance between the two frameworks, and other than List.ForEach (in this test), performance appears to have improved with .NET7. If you don't like the way I set up the test, you are welcome to change it, but whatever your test turns out to be, using a tool like BenchmarkDotNet (or others) is going to give you the fair comparison you need to make the best decision.