# Still Learning 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, function, class

I have tried if, else if, else statements, I have tried nested if statements. I have tried using variables in place of if statements. Everything functions except the Team Leader portion, there is an issue with the "TrainHours," and the repetition that it is being used, after that is corrected there is an issue with "Hours," the latest corrections was with the "GetPay()."

I have tried every different way that I can find online, and in my textbooks, but no matter what I do I get

**"'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'"**

-OR-

**"'Unknown error in unknown module Exception'"**

-personal gratitude removed for moderators- jeets82(edited)

Main Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void proWorker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pName, pShift;
        decimal pOTime, pPay;

        pName = pNameTxt.Text;


        if (pName != "" && 
            int.TryParse(pNumTxt.Text, out int pNum) && 
            decimal.TryParse(pHRateTxt.Text, out decimal pHRate) &&
            decimal.TryParse(pHoursTxt.Text, out decimal pHours))
        {
                if (dayBtn.Checked)
                {
                    ProductionWorker pWorker1 = new ProductionWorker();
                    pPay = pWorker1.getPay();
                    pOTime = pWorker1.Overtime();

                    pShift = "Day";
                    ProductionWorker pWorker = new ProductionWorker(pName, pNum, pShift, pHRate, pHours, pOTime, pPay);                      

                    MessageBox.Show(pWorker.getData());

                    StreamWriter empFile;
                    empFile = File.AppendText("proWorkerDay.txt");

                    Employee aEmp = new Employee();

                    empFile.WriteLine(pWorker.getProWorkerFile());

                    empFile.Close();
                }

                if (nightBtn.Checked)
                {
                    ProductionWorker pWorker2 = new ProductionWorker();
                    pPay = pWorker2.getPay();
                    pOTime = pWorker2.Overtime();
                    pShift = "Night";

                    ProductionWorker pWorker2N = new ProductionWorker(pName, pNum, pShift, pHRate, pHours, pOTime, pPay);
                    MessageBox.Show(pWorker2N.getData());

                    StreamWriter empFile;
                    empFile = File.AppendText("proWorkerNight.txt");

                    Employee aEmp = new Employee();

                    empFile.WriteLine(pWorker2N.getProWorkerFile());

                    empFile.Close();
                }
        }   

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter valid Production worker information");
        }

        pNameTxt.Text = "";
        pNumTxt.Text = "";
        pHRateTxt.Text = "";
        pHoursTxt.Text = "";
    }

    private void addEmp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string eName;
        int eNum;
        eName = eNameTxt.Text;

        if (Name != "" && int.TryParse(eNumTxt.Text, out eNum))
        {

            Employee employee = new Employee(eName, eNum);

            MessageBox.Show(employee.getData());

            StreamWriter empFile;
            empFile = File.AppendText("EmployeeFile.txt");

            Employee aEmp = new Employee();

            empFile.WriteLine(employee.getEmployeeFile());

            empFile.Close();                                
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter valid employee information.");
        }


    }

    private void byeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void sAddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sName, sShift;
        decimal sPay;

        sName = sNameTxt.Text;

        if (sName != "" &&
            int.TryParse(sNumTxt.Text, out int sNum) &&
            decimal.TryParse(sSalTxt.Text, out decimal sSal) &&
            decimal.TryParse(sBonusTxt.Text, out decimal sBonus))
        {

                if (sDayBtn.Checked)
                {
                    ShiftSupervisor sWorker1 = new ShiftSupervisor();
                    sPay = sWorker1.getSPay();                        

                    sShift = "Day";
                    ShiftSupervisor sWorker = new ShiftSupervisor(sName, sNum, sShift, sSal, sBonus, sPay);

                    MessageBox.Show(sWorker.getData());

                    StreamWriter empFile;
                    empFile = File.AppendText("sWorkerDay.txt");

                    Employee aEmp = new Employee();

                    empFile.WriteLine(sWorker.getSWorkerFile());

                    empFile.Close();
                }

                if (sNightBtn.Checked)
                {
                    ShiftSupervisor sWorker2 = new ShiftSupervisor();
                    sPay = sWorker2.getSPay();

                    sShift = "Night";
                    ShiftSupervisor sWorker2N = new ShiftSupervisor(sName, sNum, sShift, sSal, sBonus, sPay);
                    MessageBox.Show(sWorker2N.getData());

                    StreamWriter empFile;
                    empFile = File.AppendText("sWorkerNight.txt");

                    Employee aEmp = new Employee();

                    empFile.WriteLine(sWorker2N.getSWorkerFile());

                    empFile.Close();
                }

        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter valid Shift Supervisor information.");
        }

        sNameTxt.Text = "";
        sNumTxt.Text = "";
        sSalTxt.Text = "";
        sBonusTxt.Text = "";
    }

    private void addTLBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string tName, tShift;
        decimal tOTime, tPay;

        tName = tNameTxt.Text;


        if (tName != "" &&
            int.TryParse(tNumTxt.Text, out int tNum) &&
            decimal.TryParse(tHRateTxt.Text, out decimal tHRate) &&
            decimal.TryParse(tHoursTxt.Text, out decimal tHours) &&
            decimal.TryParse(tTrainTxt.Text, out decimal tTrain))
        {
            if (tDayBtn.Checked)
            {
                TeamLeader tWorker1 = new TeamLeader();
                tPay = tWorker1.getTPay();
                tOTime = tWorker1.Overtime();
                decimal rHours = tWorker1.ReqHours;
                decimal tTHours = tWorker1.TrainHours;

                tShift = "Day";
                TeamLeader tWorker = new TeamLeader(tName, tNum, tShift, tHRate, tHours, tOTime, rHours, tTHours, tPay);

                MessageBox.Show(tWorker.getData());

                StreamWriter empFile;
                empFile = File.AppendText("TeamLeaderDay.txt");

                Employee aEmp = new Employee();

                empFile.WriteLine(tWorker.getTeamLeaderFile());

                empFile.Close();
            }

            if (tNightBtn.Checked)
            {
                TeamLeader tWorker2 = new TeamLeader();
                tPay = tWorker2.getTPay();
                tOTime = tWorker2.Overtime();
                decimal rHours = tWorker2.ReqHours;
                decimal tTHours = tWorker2.TrainHours;

                tShift = "Day";
                TeamLeader tWorker2N = new TeamLeader(tName, tNum, tShift, tHRate, tHours, tOTime, rHours, tTHours, tPay);
                MessageBox.Show(tWorker2N.getData());

                StreamWriter empFile;
                empFile = File.AppendText("TeamLeaderNight.txt");

                Employee aEmp = new Employee();

                empFile.WriteLine(tWorker2N.getTeamLeaderFile());

                empFile.Close();
            }
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter valid Production worker information");
        }

        tNameTxt.Text = "";
        tNumTxt.Text = "";
        tHRateTxt.Text = "";
        tHoursTxt.Text = "";
        tTrainTxt.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Base Class:

```
class Employee
{
    private string _name;
    private int _number;
    private string _empAddList;

    public Employee(string name, int num)
    {
        _name = name;
        _number = num;
        _empAddList = name + " " + num.ToString();
    }

    public Employee()
    {
        _name = "";
        _number = 0;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public int Number
    {
        get { return _number; }
        set { _number = value; }
    }

    public string EmpAddList
    {
        get { return _empAddList; }
        set { _empAddList = value; }
    }

    //define method to return the values
    public virtual string getData()
    {
        string line = "";
        line += " Name: \t\t" + this.Name + "\n";
        line += " Number: \t" + this.Number;
        return line;
    }

    public string getEmployeeFile()
    {
        string line = "";
        line += this.Name + "," + this.Number;
        return line;
    }

}

abstract class Employee1 : Employee
{
    public abstract decimal Overtime();
    public abstract decimal getPay();
}
```

***PROBLEM CLASS*** I have fixed almost every portion and every time I fix something it gives me a different error or StackOverflowException.

```
class TeamLeader : Employee
{
    private string _shiftNum;
    private decimal _hourlyRate;
    private decimal _reqHours;
    private decimal _trainHours;
    private decimal _hours;
    private decimal _overtime;
    private decimal _oT;


    public string ShiftNum
    {
        get { return _shiftNum; }
        set
        {
            if (_shiftNum == "Day Shift")
            {
                _shiftNum = "Day";
            }

            else
            {
                _shiftNum = "Night";
            }
        }
    }

    public decimal HourlyRate
    {
        get { return _hourlyRate; }
        set { _hourlyRate = value; }
    }

    public decimal Hours
    {
        get { return _hours; }
        set { _hours = value; }
    }

    public decimal ReqHours
    {
        get { return _reqHours; }
        set { _reqHours = value; }
    }

    public decimal TrainHours
    {
        get { return _trainHours; }
        set { _trainHours = value; }
    }

    public decimal Overtime()
    {
        decimal oTime = 0;

        if (Hours > 40)
        {
            _oT = Hours - 40;
            oTime = (HourlyRate * 1.5m) * _oT;
        }

        else
        {
            oTime = 0;
        }

        return oTime;
    }

    public decimal getTBonus()
    {
        decimal tBonus = 0;            
        if (TrainHours <= 0 && Hours <= 0)
        { tBonus = 0; }

        if (TrainHours >= (Hours * .15m))
        { tBonus = getTPay() * .15m; }

        if (TrainHours >= (Hours * .1m))
        { tBonus = getTPay() * .125m; }

        if (TrainHours >= (Hours * .08m))
        { tBonus = getTPay() * .05m; }

        else
        { tBonus = getTPay() * .025m; }

        return tBonus;
    }

    public decimal getTTrainHours()
    {
        decimal tHours = 0;
        if (TrainHours <= 0 && Hours <= 0)
        { tHours = 0; }

        if (TrainHours >= (Hours * .15m))
        { tHours = Hours * .15m; }

        else if (TrainHours <= (Hours * .1m))
        { tHours = Hours * .125m; }

        else if (TrainHours <= (Hours * .08m))
        { tHours = Hours * .05m; }

        else
        { tHours = Hours * .025m; }

        return tHours;
    }

    public decimal getTPay()
    {
        decimal paid = 0;

        if (Hours <= 0)
        { paid = 0; }

        if (Hours > 40)
        { paid = (HourlyRate * 40) + Overtime() + getTBonus(); }

        else
        { paid = (Hours * HourlyRate) + getTBonus(); }

        return paid;
    }

    public TeamLeader(string name, int num, string shift, decimal hr, decimal hours, decimal oTime, decimal rHours, decimal tTHours, decimal pay) : base(name, num)
    {
        _shiftNum = shift;
        _hourlyRate = hr;
        _hours = hours;
        _overtime = oTime;
        _trainHours = rHours;
        _reqHours = tTHours;

    }

    public TeamLeader()
    {
        _shiftNum = "";
        _hourlyRate = 0;
        _hours = 0;
        _overtime = 0;
        _trainHours = 0;
        _reqHours = 0;
    }

    public override string getData()
    {
        string line = "";
        line += " Name: \t" + this.Name + "\n";
        line += " Number: \t" + this.Number + "\n";
        line += " Shift Number: \t" + this.ShiftNum + "\n";
        line += " Hourly Rate: \t" + this.HourlyRate.ToString("C") + "\n";
        line += " Hours Worked: \t" + this.Hours + "\n";
        line += " Training Hours: \t" + this.TrainHours.ToString() + "\n";
        line += " Overtime Hours: \t" + (this.Hours - 40) + "\n";
        line += " Overtime Pay: \t" + this.Overtime().ToString("C") + "\n";            
        line += " Bonus Multiplier: \t" + this.getTTrainHours().ToString("P") + "\n";
        line += " Bonus: \t" + this.getTBonus().ToString("C") + "\n";
        line += " Weekly Pay: \t" + this.getTPay().ToString("C");

        return line;
    }

    public string getTeamLeaderFile()
    {
        string line = "";
        line += this.Name + "," + this.Number + "," + this.ShiftNum + "," + this.HourlyRate.ToString() + "," + this.Hours + "," + this.TrainHours.ToString() + "," + (this.Hours - 40) + "," + 
            this.Overtime().ToString() + "," + this.getTTrainHours().ToString("P") + "," + this.getTBonus().ToString("C") + "," + this.getTPay().ToString();
        return line;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There's a joke about a speak-your-weight machine, where a large person stands on it, and it says "one person at a time, please!". This question is a bit like that. Your question needs to focus on one issue. You need to provide a [mcve] (for example, [edit] your question to remove all the commented code). Pick *one* exception, and show us the code when that happens; and tell us what line it happens on. I sympathise with the background info, but it's not relevant to the question: try to focus on the issue. The "how to ask" uses the phrase "talking to a busy colleague".

Comment: I didn't down vote. I'm trying to help. You mentioned 2 exceptions, not just one. Your experience here will be bad if you don't learn [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For example, let me offer this unrelated tip: `StreamWriter` is IDisposable so should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close it because it will be closed by the implicit Dispose as it exits the block.

Comment: I'd like to clarify and apologize. I had directed that portion at @Uwe Keim who did downvote my question without explanation and removed a pre-emptive appreciation I had shown. Do you have some direction on how to better phrase my question? I will gladly try to be more direct.

Comment: No problem: as you said yourself, we've all been there, and glad you found your answer. Don't take the down votes to heart - StackOverflow is a powerful tool; but one has to learn how to use it. There are lots of tips on the 'How to ask' page, and the MCVE page is regularly quoted, and applies here: It is all too easy to just throw a load of code at StackOverflow and say "help!", but that does not make a good question, and I fear this question strayed too much in that direction, which may have drawn the down votes. Look on meta.stackoverflow.com for info on how people use this site.Best wishes

Comment: @Richardissimo I would like to thank you. It took some time. Another whole day in fact, but I learned to use the: FileStream, and: Using to achieve the IDisposable. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in `TeamLeader::getData()`

`getTBonus()` is calling `getTPay()` which is calling `getTBonus()` again causing an infinite loop, which will throw the `StackOverflowException`.

You might try using `if...else if` in those methods instead of just `if`.

```
public decimal getTBonus()
{
    decimal tBonus = 0;
    if (TrainHours <= 0 && Hours <= 0)
    { tBonus = 0; }

    else if (TrainHours >= (Hours * .15m))
    { tBonus = getTPay() * .15m; }

    else if (TrainHours >= (Hours * .1m))
    { tBonus = getTPay() * .125m; }

    else if (TrainHours >= (Hours * .08m))
    { tBonus = getTPay() * .05m; }

    else
    { tBonus = getTPay() * .025m; }

    return tBonus;
}

public decimal getTPay()
{
    decimal paid = 0;

    if (Hours <= 0)
    { paid = 0; }

    else if (Hours > 40)
    { paid = (HourlyRate * 40) + Overtime() + getTBonus(); }

    else
    { paid = (Hours * HourlyRate) + getTBonus(); }

    return paid;
}
```

Comment: The infinite loop might be fixable by changing "get T bonus *amount*" to "get T bonus *percentage*" (which doesn't need to call getTPay)

Comment: The problem persists and just pops up in a different place. This time it threw the same exception

-System.StackOverflowException
  HResult=0x800703E9
  Message=Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.


at the 
        public decimal Hours
        {
            get { return _hours; }
            set { _hours = value; }
        }

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by removing the getBonus() from the getPay() method. After I did that I added a new variable that added them together in the getData() method. This worked. Now I just need to figure out why my TrainHours will not populate. Thank you all that was helpful in guiding me to the answer.

**decimal weeklyPay = getTBonus() + getTPay();**

line += " Weekly Pay: \t" + weeklyPay.ToString("C");