# How to: Add a string to a string array using File.ReadAllLines

Tags: c#, arrays, string, file.readalllines

**How to: Add a string to a string array using File.ReadAllLines**

I think the question is clear: I want to add a new string to an existing string array, which gets ist content from a `File.ReadAllLines`.

```
public void CreateNewFolder()
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(stringFile, Encoding.UTF8);
    lines[lines.Length + 1] = "Test";
    File.WriteAllLines(stringFile, lines, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

The index of the array is "too small", but I do not know why.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440265/how-to-add-a-string-to-a-string-array-theres-no-add-function

Comment: Simplest Answer: Use a list instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused since the length of the array is fixed and the and the last index (where you wanna add the new item) is always outside the array.
You can use a list instead:

```
public void CreateNewFolder()
{
    List<String> lines = File.ReadAllLines(stringFile, Encoding.UTF8).ToList();
    lines.Add("Test");
    File.WriteAllLines(stringFile, lines.ToArray(), Encoding.UTF8);
    //Calling the ToArray method for lines is not necessary 
}
```

Comment: You might want to add to your answer that he gets the error because an array has a fixed length once defined. List is the way to go. +1

Comment: There is no definition for `ToList()`.

Comment: @middelpat: Good suggestion, will add it

Comment: @Exception include "using System.Linq;"

Comment: Final answer! Perfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: Additional question: What's the difference between `List<String>` and `List<string>`?

Comment: String is a System type while string is a built in type

Comment: Actually, no difference.

Comment: @amnezjak: The difference is only visible when use the System String in C++, then the way it works will be really really different from string and casting these two is also a long story (C++), but in C# they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you try to change an item beyond current array length. You can use [`Array.Resize<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to resize array first and then change last item

```
public void CreateNewFolder()
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(stringFile, Encoding.UTF8);
    Array.Resize(ref lines, lines.Length + 1);
    lines[lines.Length - 1] = "Test";
    File.WriteAllLines(stringFile, lines, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```