# Mutating to a new string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm doing an exercise that says I have to enter a phrase and put it in array, then I have to delete all the repeated characters and show the new phrase.
I did it like this but I don't know how to get char from string array and put it into another string array.

PS: I must only use the basics of C# and arrays :(

```
namespace Exercice3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Entrez une phrase SVP!!");
            string phrase = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] phraseArray = new string[]{ phrase };
            string[] newPhrase = new string[phrase.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i <= phrase.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= phrase.Length - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (phraseArray[i] != phraseArray[j])
                        newPhrase = phraseArray[i]; //Probleme here 
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(newPhrase);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: newPhrase.Add(pharseArray[i]) this add new item into array. = only set new array into newParse and phraseArray[i] is not an array i guess.

Comment: Is it possible you're suppose to use the string as a character array (`char[]`), and not as an array of strings?

Comment: string[] does not contain a definition for "add..

Comment: ah so you need add it with index https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440265/how-to-add-a-string-to-a-string-array-theres-no-add-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this would do it. You don't have to do it this way...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var newColl = new List<char>();

        foreach(char c in "aaabbbccc".ToCharArray())
        {
            if (!newColl.Contains(c))
                newColl.Add(c);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(new string(newColl.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Output:

> abc

**Array-only method**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const string orig = "aaabbbcccddd";
        int origLen = orig.Length;
        char[] newArr = new char[origLen]; // get max possible spots in arr
        int newCount = 0;


        for(int i = 0; i < origLen; i++)
        {
            bool yes = false;

            for(int j = 0; j < newCount + 1; j++)
            {

                if (newArr[j] == orig[i])
                {    
                    yes = true;
                    break;
                }

            }

            if (!yes)
            {
                newArr[newCount] = orig[i];
                newCount++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(new string(newArr));
    }
}
```

Output:

> abcd

Comment: i know but my teacher wil not accept that because he says that we have just use the basics of c# like if and else statement, loops and arrays

Comment: I am glad - you have good teacher. If I have time, I add second solution

Comment: Thank you i started to understand a little bit, really thank you, you helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you are using arrays of strings. That is inappropriate because you are trying to iterate the *characters* of the string.

You need to construct your array of characters like this:

```
char[] phraseArray = phrase.ToCharArray();
```

This should allow you the ability to iterate the set of characters, check for duplicates, and form the new character array.

Comment: how can i do that without using TocharArray() ?

Comment: can you show me how can i do that ("This should allow you the ability to iterate the set of characters, check for duplicates, and form the new character array.") ??

Comment: @RedaTaha You can simply access chars of string by index: `char myChar = phrase[indexNumber];`. Doing so for each of the chars and inserting it into `phraseArray` if the char has not already been inserted will give you what is needed. Arrays are fixed-length, but since you are removing duplicate chars, the new array will be of shorter or equal size than original one, so just make it the same size as `phrase`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException` is because if you look at the two arrays:

```
string[] phraseArray = new string[]{ phrase };
```

And

```
string[] newPhrase = new string[phrase.Length];
```

The length of both arrays are completely different, `phraseArray` has a length of 1 and newPhrase will be set to the length of your phrase, so if you insert a world of more than 1 character both arrays will not match and then either:

```
if (phraseArray[i] != phraseArray[j])
```

Or

```
newPhrase = phraseArray[i];
```

Will fail, specially `newPhrase = phraseArray[i];`, because here you're trying to replace `newPhrase` an array, for a character `phrase[i]`. Basically your solution won't work. So what you can do is do what **@Travis** suggested, basically change your arrays from `String[]`to `char[]`, then:

```
char[] phraseArray = phrase.ToCharArray();
```

Or Instead of using arrays you can just use another string to filter your phrase. The first string being your **phrase** and the second would be the string you'd add your non repeated characters to. basically this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Entrez une phrase SVP!!");
string phrase = Console.ReadLine();
string newPhrase = ""; 

// loop through each character in phrase        
for (int i = 0; i < phrase.Length; i++) {
   // We check if the character of phrease is within our newPhrase, if it isn't we add it, otherwise do nothing
   if (newPhrase.IndexOf(phrase[i]) == -1) 
        newPhrase += phrase[i]; // here we add it to newPhrase
}

Console.WriteLine(newPhrase);
```

Don't forget to read the comments in the code.

**Edit:**

Based on the comments and suggestions given I implemented a similar solution:

```
Console.WriteLine("Entrez une phrase SVP!!");
char[] phrase = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
char[] newPhrase = new char[phrase.Length]; 
int index = 0;

// loop through each character in phrase        
for (int i = 0; i < phrase.Length; i++) {
  // We check if the character of phrease is within our newPhrase, if it isn't we add it, otherwise do nothing
  if (Array.IndexOf(newPhrase, phrase[i]) == -1) 
      newPhrase[index++] = phrase[i]; // here we add it to newPhrase
}

Console.WriteLine(newPhrase);
```

Comment: Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be changed after the object is created. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string Let him have an array and modify the values at each index.

Comment: Nvm I see your point. But don't you think using two strings is the same as using two char arrays, literally. So in theory wouldn't it be the same thing?

Comment: @Ghukas not sooo immutable, i give you pointers, unsafe, and reflection ;)

Comment: @Bargros It's not 2 strings, it's as many strings as the number of times the `if` statement's condition is satisfied. In case of array the "waste" is `phrase.Length - number_of_unique_chars` chars. Also I'd not use `.IndexOf()` but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Yep I see your point, arrays would be a better alternative, I was being a bit lazy there, thanks for the pointer.