# How to first 'Split a string to an Array' then 'Add something to that Array'? || C# Console App

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split, resize

I'm trying to create a program that splits a string to an array then adds 
to that array.

Splitting the string works but adding to the array is really putting up a 
fight.

```
//here i create the text
string text = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine();

//Here i split my text to elements in an Array 
var punctuation = text.Where(Char.IsPunctuation).Distinct().ToArray();
var words = text.Split().Select(x => x.Trim(punctuation));

//here i display the splitted string
foreach (string x in words)
{
  Console.WriteLine(x);
}

//Here a try to add something to the Array
Array.words(ref words, words.Length + 1);
words[words.Length - 1] = "addThis";

//I try to display the updated array
foreach (var x in words)
{
  Console.WriteLine(x);
}

//Here are the error messages |*error*|
Array.|*words*|(ref words, words.|*Length*| + 1);
words[words.|*Length*| - 1] = "addThis";
```

'Array' does not contain definition for 'words'

Does not contain definition for Length

Does not contain definition for length */

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440265/how-to-add-a-string-to-a-string-array-theres-no-add-function and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126915/how-do-i-split-a-string-by-a-multi-character-delimiter-in-c  there are tons of answers for your two questions. It took less than 30 seconds

Comment: How did you come up with using `Array.words`?

Comment: I think you mean `Array.Resize`, not `Array.words`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a string to a string\[\] array? There's no .Add function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440265/how-to-add-a-string-to-a-string-array-theres-no-add-function)

Comment: Always use the right tool ! Arrays are not made for this; use List<T> !

Comment: My reason for doing this is to complete a school project. This code worked though.

string[] resize = new string[] { "January", "February", "Marts", "April", "May", 
    "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" 
};

                        Array.Resize(ref resize, resize.Length + 1);
                        resize[resize.Length - 1] = "addThis";
                        foreach (var x in resize)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(x);
                        }

Answer (score 2):

Convert the IEnumerable to List:

```
var words = text.Split().Select(x => x.Trim(punctuation)).ToList();
```

Once it is a list, you can call `Add`

```
words.Add("addThis");
```

Comment: think ill try with array first but i appreciate the answer !

Answer (score 0):

Technically, if you want to split on *punctuation*, I suggest `Regex.Split` instead of `string.Split`

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string text = 
    @"Text with punctuation: comma, full stop. Apostroph's and ""quotation?"" - ! Yes!";

  var result = Regex.Split(text, @"\p{P}");

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
Text with punctuation      # Space is not a punctuation, 3 words combined
 comma
 full stop
 Apostroph                 # apostroph ' is a punctuation, split as required
s and 
quotation



 Yes
```

if you want to add up some items, I suggest *Linq* `Concat()` and `.ToArray()`:

```
    string text = 

    string[] words = Regex
      .Split(text, @"\p{P}")
      .Concat(new string[] {"addThis"})
      .ToArray();
```

However, it seems that you want to *extract words*, not to *split on puctuation* which you can do matching these words:

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string text = 
    @"Text with punctuation: comma, full stop. Apostroph's and ""quotation?"" - ! Yes!";

  string[] words = Regex
    .Matches(text, @"[\p{L}']+") // Let word be one or more letters or apostrophs
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .Concat(new string[] { "addThis"})
    .ToArray();

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
Text
with
punctuation
comma
full
stop
Apostroph's
and
quotation
Yes
addThis
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! im gonna look into Regex and Concat to understand this better :)