# Bypassing C#'s type safeguards and storing an Integer in a String

Tags: c#, debugging, unsafe

Have a look at the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = null;
    string[] myArray = new string[1];

    { } // do something evil here

    if (s.GetType() == typeof(int))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This should not happen!"); 
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Is there any way to get `This should not happen` to write? One would assume not. However, it can be done with the debugger: Put a breakpoint into the line `{ } // do something evil here` and execute the following commands in the Immediate Window before continuing:

```
((object[])myArray)[0] = 99;
s = myArray[0];
```

Execution continues and `This should not happen` will be printed. Tested with Visual Studio 2008; here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Is this kind of trickery only possible with the debugger or is there some way to do such an "unsafe assignment" in code?

(Obviously, I ask only out of scientific curiosity. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17640882/87698) and the related comments made me ask this question.)

Comment: I think it's one of these "who debugs the debugger" questions: I think you found a bug in the VS debugger.

Comment: Very interesting topic, but isn't this question just a duplicate of the question you link?

Comment: Being able to break the rules is rather the point of a debugger.  You can arbitrarily change code execution order, freeze a thread, mutate a string, directly poke bytes in the GC heap, etc.  Sure you can do this in code as well, pointers let you poke whatever you want.  It just isn't very useful.

Comment: First box an int and then use one of the reinterpret cast tricks. For example by creating a union using explicit layout.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: It's the same topic but a different question (`Why does this happen?` vs. `Can this be done in code as well?`).

Comment: @HansPassant Can you also do an assignment like `someStringVariable = new object();` through the debugger? If not, why the difference between the type-safety of a "single" variable and that of an array entry? Would that be by design, or by "coincidence"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One technique is using `LayoutKind.Explicit` to implement a union which can be used to reinterpret cast an arbitrary object to string. First box an int, then assign it to the `object` field of the union and then read out the string field.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Evil
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public string s;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public object o;
}

string ReinterpretCastToString(object o)
{
    Evil evil=new Evil();
    evil.o=o;
    return evil.s;
}

void Main()
{
    string s = ReinterpretCastToString(1);

    if (s.GetType() == typeof(int))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This should not happen!"); 
    }
}
```

This is most likely undefined behavior that may stop working at any time. Obviously you shouldn't use this in a real program.

Comment: I'm surprised that this even compiles, given that the size of the string cannot be known at compile time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey All references have the same size 4 or 8 bytes depending on the CPU architecture. This is essentially casting from one pointer type to another.

Comment: Oh crap, just noticed a third-part lib used in one of my projects actually uses this technique to cast between `int[]` and `float[]`.