# C# Arrays of wrong type possible?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I would not have thought that its possible, but it seems you somehow can create and fill an C# array of a "wrong" type.

I stumbled upon the following anomaly in Unity 4.2.1 today:

```
Editor[] editors = ActiveEditorTracker.sharedTracker.activeEditors;
Debug.Log(editors.GetType().Name);
Debug.Log(editors.GetType().GetElementType().Name);
Debug.Log(typeof(Editor).IsAssignableFrom(editors[0].GetType()));
Debug.Log(typeof(Editor).IsAssignableFrom(editors.GetType().GetElementType()));
```

It prints the following output:

```
MonoBehaviour[]
MonoBehaviour
True
False
```

In Unity, the class "MonoBehaviour" and "Editor" are unrelated slibbings (both inherit from UnityEngine.Object, but neither from the other). They are not assignable to each other or related in any way I can see that would make the above output possible.

So my question is: The Heck?

More detailed question: How is it possible to create an array of the "wrong" type and fill it with elements of the "right" type? I want to do this too! How do I circumvent the array checks from C#? (maybe using unsafe()?)

My current gut-feeling is, that C# only prevent *writing* to the wrong array (via ArrayTypeMismatchException), but if you somehow magically fill the array (in case of Unity, probably using dark C++ magic), it just works..?

(Funny also: If I do this `editors[0] = editors[0]` I get the mentioned ArrayTypeMismatchException)

Edit: Also funny: `Array self = editors; editors = (Editor[])self;` throws an `InvalidCastException`

Comment: When `editors[0]` has a type that _is_ assignable "to" `Editor` (your "True" output), why would the assignment `editors[0] = editors[0]` throw `ArrayTypeMismatchException`?

Comment: Will the code `Array self = editors; editors = (Editor[])self;` aslo fail with a runtime exception?

Comment: You: _I want to do this too!_ One way of doing it is in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17643662/1336654). You simply need to change the type of the field in `Evil` from `string` (which that example uses) to `Editor[]`. After that you can put ***any*** object into an `Editor[]` reference. Nasty.

Comment: _When editors[0] has a type that is assignable "to" Editor (your "True" output), why would the assignment editors[0] = editors[0] throw ArrayTypeMismatchException_

Because the runtime type of the array itself is not Editor[] but MonoBehaviour[] (and its ElementType is MonoBehaviour). Yea.. I know something is fishy here, but I have it before my very eyes.. The static type of my variable "editors" does not match the runtime type. :-O

Comment: _Will the code Array self = editors; editors = (Editor[])self; aslo fail with a runtime exception?_

Yes, it throws an `InvalidCastException`. Which is comforting to me - at least something I excpected :-D

Comment: _One way of doing it is in this answer._

Mh.. yea.. interesting. Interestingly, the type Editor is marked with `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` when using a disassembler, although its a class type. And when trying to get the attribute via runtime reflection, its not there anymore.. :-O

Answer (score 0):

Some magic

```
Editor[] editors =  ActiveEditorTracker.sharedTracker.activeEditors;

    Editor e0 = editors[0];
    Editor e1 = editors[1];
    Editor e2 = editors[2];

    Editor[] test = {e0, e1, e2};

    Debug.Log(test.GetType());

    Debug.Log(typeof(Editor).IsAssignableFrom(test[0].GetType()));
    Debug.Log(typeof(Editor).IsAssignableFrom(test.GetType().GetElementType()));
```

UnityEditor.Editor[]
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

True
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

True
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

Comment: It works fine and now it's a Editor array, not MonoBehaviour array.