# .Net Remoting versus WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-remoting

I am wondering that I can do same thing from both .net remoting and WCF, then why WCF is more preferred over .Net remoting. Where can I choose (or in which situation) .Net remoting or WCF?

Comment: You can use `Array` to store homogeneous data elements then why `Collections` is prefered??

Comment: because Array can store only one type of data but collections can store user defined data types!!

Comment: What do you meant by that? Array can store anything if collection can do. Under the hood collections uses arrays internally

Comment: then try to store string type data into int type array! and if you done then notify me!!!

Comment: Ok, you pls show me how to add `string` to `List<int>`.

Comment: And upon your interest, check my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640882/can-a-string-hold-system-object-inside-it). I've shown how to do that :)

Comment: list<myClass> where myClass is user defined data type

Comment: Your point? Can't get you

Comment: class myclass
    {
        public string name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

Comment: I know that is a class, complete your sentence pls. You mean array can't store `myclass`?

Comment: `MyClass[] myClasses = new MyClass[10]` Won't this work for your class ?

Comment: public   class myclass
    {
        public string name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
then define this

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**.NET Remoting** applications can use the HTTP, TCP, and SMTP protocols whereas **WCF** can use named pipes and MSMQ as well along with all these protocols.

You may find the best answer here: [From .NET Remoting to the Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730857%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> **Conclusion**
>
> As you have seen, a migration from .NET Remoting to WCF is not a task
> you have to be afraid of. For most applications, a simple three-step
> process can bring your application to the new platform. In most cases,
> you will only have to mark your interface contracts with
> [ServiceContract] and [OperationContract], your data structures with
> [DataContract] and [DataMember] and maybe change some parts of your
> activation model to be based on sessions instead of client-activated
> objects.
>
> If you decide that you want to take advantage of the features
> of the Windows Communication Foundation, the complete migration from
> .NET Remoting to WCF should therefore be a rather easy task for the
> majority of applications.

You may also find the performance difference between the two in [A Performance Comparison of Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) with Existing Distributed Communication Technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx)

> When migrating distributed applications written with ASP.NET Web
> Services, WSE, .NET Enterprise Services and .NET Remoting to WCF, the
> performance is at least comparable to the other existing Microsoft
> distributed communication technologies. **In most cases, the performance
> is significantly better for WCF over the other existing technologies.
> Another important characteristic of WCF is that the throughput
> performance is inherently scalable from a uni processor to quad
> processor.**
>
> **To summarize the results, WCF is 25%—50% faster than ASP.NET Web
> Services, and approximately 25% faster than .NET Remoting**. Comparison
> with .NET Enterprise Service is load dependant, as in one case WCF is
> nearly 100% faster but in another scenario it is nearly 25% slower.
> For WSE 2.0/3.0 implementations, migrating them to WCF will obviously
> provide the most significant performance gains of almost 4x.

Comment: Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Can't .NetRemoting do pipe communication using IpcChannel (ipc://) ?

Answer (score 1):

WCF (Windows Communication Foundation), which has code-named Indigo, is a technology by which pieces of software can communicate with one another.

Windows Communication Foundation consists of several new sets of classes added to the second version, the 2.0 version, of the Microsoft .NET Framework Class Library.

It gives the feature of Web services as well as .Net Remoting. Looking into core - Windows Communication Foundation provides a software factory template for software communication, consisting of a modeling language called the Service Model, and a programming framework called the Channel Layer. One can configure the endpoints defined by an address, a binding, and a contract just by using configuration file.

source is [WCF](https://sites.google.com/site/dotnetbydeepak/home/difference-between-wcf-webservices-and-remoting)

Comment: Please, if you are going to copy/paste an answer from a website, give attribution to it. Otherwise, you are plagiarising. Source: "[*What is WCF?*](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/what-is-wcf1)" on C# corner, by [Vishal Mehra](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/members/vishal-mehra3).

Comment: Yeah. I referred it from a website. Btw source is [WCF](https://sites.google.com/site/dotnetbydeepak/home/difference-between-wcf-webservices-and-remoting)

Comment: thank you for the advice & appreciated it.  ^_^ Just edited the answer above.