# Exception for calling ToList() after conversion from uint[] to int[] in C#

Tags: c#

I get an exception `System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Source array type cannot be assigned to destination array type` for this code snippet:

```
var uints = GetArray();
if (uints is int[])
{
    var list = ((int[])uints).ToList(); // fails when call ToList()
}

private Array GetArray()
{
    var result = new uint[] { uint.MaxValue, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    return result;
}
```

Then I resort to Jon's answer in [Why does "int[] is uint[] == true" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593730/why-does-int-is-uint-true-in-c-sharp), it told me that because of `GetArray()` returns an `Array`, the conversion was postponed in runtime, and CLR allows this kind of `int[] to uint[](vice versa)` cast. And it actually works fine if I check values after conversion:

```
foreach (var i in ((int[])units))
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(i.GetType());
    System.Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

I would get:

```
System.Int32
-1
System.Int32
2
//skipped...
```

However I kind of get confused why it would fail when calling `ToList()`, as this code below will work fine?

```
internal class Animal
{
}

internal class Cat : Animal
{
}

var cats = new Cat[] { new Cat(), new Cat() };
List<Animal> animals = ((Animal[])cats).ToList(); //no exception
```

Comment: Your example for code that works doesn't seem the same as your issue. Cat is an Animal, int is not a uint

Comment: Sorry, I was trying the example in LINQPad with optimizations turned on and it incorrectly reported which line of code that failed.

Comment: As I expected cast from `uint[]` to `int[]` is NOP check this: `int[] x = ((int[])uints); Console.WriteLine(x.GetType());` it prints `System.UInt32[]` LOL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening here? Let's start with `foreach` loop, C# compiler optimizes them heavily especially when you use them with arrays - they are basically changes to normal `for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) { }` - so the example with

```
foreach (var i in ((int[])units))
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(i.GetType());
    System.Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

cannot be trusted, BTW `foreach` can also perform cast on element type it is better to try generic `Array.GetValue` method:

```
int[] x = ((int[])uints);
Console.WriteLine(x.GetValue(0).GetType()); // System.UInt32

Console.WriteLine(x[0].GetType()); // System.Int32
```

So even access `x[0]` can return already casted value but `Array.GetValue` returned what was already there an `uint`.

Let's do another experiment:

```
Console.WriteLine(x.GetType()); // System.UInt32[]

Console.WriteLine(uints.GetType()); // System.UInt32[]

Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(x, uints)); // True
```

This assures us that cast in `var x = (int[])uints` is a NOP - no operation, it does nothing at all. Especially 3th line show us the we get exactly the same instance.

Now inside [List constructor](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs.html#https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs.html) we have lines

```
_items = new T[count];
c.CopyTo(_items, 0);
```

that actually throw Array mismatch exception.

But why this exception wasn't thrown earlier e.g. when `GetEnumerator()` is called I don't know myself, I expected exception to be thrown on lines

```
x.GetEnumerator()
```

because types `IEnumerable<int>` and `IEnumerable<uint>` are not compatible but none was - maybe because .NET returns here `System.Array+SZArrayEnumerator` that is the same for every value type array.

EDIT: (After example with Cat)
Array covariance in C# assures us that any array of reference types can be assigned to `object[]` and that array of type `Subclass[]` can be assigned to `BaseClass[]`. The case with value types is different since they can have different sizes and/or conversion behaviours (`uint` vs `int`).

`ToList` uses internally `Array.Copy` call, when we look at `Array.Copy` implementation in CRL: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755/src/classlibnative/bcltype/arraynative.cpp#L328 we see that array can be copied only if value types have compatible singess which is checked by another util function https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/32f0f9721afb584b4a14d69135bea7ddc129f755/src/vm/invokeutil.h#L196

The other question is why it was implemented this way...

Comment: I tried `Array cats = new Cat[] { new Cat(), new Cat() };` `var animals = (Animal[])cats;` `System.Console.WriteLine(cats.GetType()); // Cat[]` `System.Console.WriteLine(animals.GetType()); // Cat[]`  `System.Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(cats, animals)); // True` Since `IEnumerable<Cat>` and `IEnumerable<Animal>` are not compatible, animals.ToList() would also fail?

Comment: @KungPaoChicken `int` and `uint` types are not compatible but `Cat` and `Animal` are (both are references with child parent relation), this is long known issue with array variance in c#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619139/covariance-and-contravariance-with-c-sharp-arrays (basically every array  of reference types is convertible to `object[]`). Since .NET array implementation always returns `System.Array+SZArrayEnumerator` and since `IEnumerable<out T>` (see `out` before `T`) is covariant it will works without any exceptions. I guess my example with `IEnumerable` was unfortunate

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to cast the array to `int[]` when it is a `uint[]`. That by itself is fine, since both `int[]` and `uint[]` are of type `Array`, and casting an Array object of type `uint[]` as an `int[]` (or vice versa) is allowed (for some reason).

The problem comes when you try to then convert it to a List. The method is trying to create a List of type `int` because that's the type you specified, but that's not what the type of the array actually is.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying the example in LINQPad with optimizations turned on and it incorrectly reported which line of code that failed.