# Fast IEnumerable<enum1> to List<enum2> convertation

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have two same enums that have the same names of members, but they are in different namespaces so they are "different types", but in fact namespace1.enum1 {a,b,c,d,e,f} and namespace2.enum2 {a,b,c,d,e,f}

How is the easiest way to convert `IEnumerable<enum1>` to `List<enum2>` without using loops?

Comment: There isn't a *safe* way of doing this without loops, but if you're able to use `unsafe` code, you can transmute the memory directly via a cast. This might result in invalid memory, if the enums have different memory layouts, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well something's going to loop *somewhere*, but it doesn't have to be in your code. Just a LINQ `Select` will be fine:

```
var result = original.Select(x => (Enum2) x).ToList();
```

Comment: Would the cast still work if done like this `=> (Enum2)(int)x`? is is it not necessary?

Comment: @Nkosi: Yes, but you don't need to.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use `Cast` (still O(n) :-))

```
var result = original.Cast<int>().Cast<Enum2>().ToList();
```

**Warning**
It seems that this will not always work as expected (`InvalidCastException` can be thrown in some cases). 
See comments to figure out why.

Comment: That will actually throw an exception in some cases due to an inappropriate optimization that `Cast` makes. Bizarre, but true. There's another post about it somewhere - will try to dig it up.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40604183/ (The `int`/`uint` is like `int`/enum.)

Comment: @JonSkeet If the underlying type for both enums is the same then would that still be an issue here?  Though it's probably worth avoiding this just because of the boxing.

Comment: @JonSkeet hmm, nice issue. I'll leave the answer for future readers.