# Why is "new int[n] is object[]" false? And why is "int[] is object[] arr" a pattern error?

Tags: c#

Why is an array of ints not an array of objects? And why can a pattern of type 'object[]' not be used for 'int[]'?

```
    1 is object
    True
    new int[10] is object
    True
    new int[10] is object[]         // Why?
    False
    (Array)new int[10] is object[]
    False
    (Array)new object[10] is object[]
    True
    new object() is object
    True
    new object[10] is object
    True
    new object[10] is object[]
    True

    int[] arr = new int[10];
    // Why the compilation error?
    // error CS8121: An expression of type 'int[]' cannot be handled by a pattern of type 'object[]'
    if (arr is object[] objArr)   
        Console.WriteLine(objArr);
    // And this works:        
    if ((Array)arr is object[] objArr)
        Console.WriteLine(objArr);
```

I came across this line in the source code: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Array.cs,1644

.NET version is 3.1.10 (same on mono 6.4.0).

Comment: While you can **cast** an array of numbers to an array of objects - because arrays are co-variant - the former is not **defined** to be an instance of the latter. The `is`-checks does not consider assignability, but inheritance.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619139/covariance-and-contravariance-with-c-sharp-arrays

Answer (score 5):

Actually (if I understand the problem correctly), in this case, it's because *value types* are not *covariant*:

```
(Array)new string[10] is object[] 
true

(Array)new int[10] is object[]
false
```

The *CLR* disallows it because it needs to preserve the *identity*, where as boxing will not, it fundamentally changes the type in memory

[Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) has a great blog post about *identity* at [Representation and identity](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/):

> covariant and contravariant conversions of interface and delegate
>   types require that all varying type arguments be of reference types.
>   To ensure that a variant reference conversion is always
>   identity-preserving, all of the conversions involving type arguments
>   must also be identity-preserving. The easiest way to ensure that all
>   the non-trivial conversions on type arguments are identity-preserving
>   is to restrict them to be reference conversions.

Comment: While writing my answer I also stumbled about the value-type-arrays. Didn´t know that this is only allowed for reference-type-arrays.

Answer (score 4):

Let´s make an example that contains lists instead of arrays, because the same semantics apply.

Assume you have a list of base-class `Animal`. **If** you could cast `List<Giraffe>` to `List<Animal>`, you can do this also:

```
((List<Animal> myGiraffes).Add(new Lion())
```

which surely breaks your concept of type-safety. That´s why `List<T>` is not co-variant. In your case you have an array, which - by error or design - however **is** co-variant. Thus you can **convert** an array of any type to an array of type `object`.

```
object[] a = new string[0];
```

Also have a look at [Why are arrays covariant but generics are invariant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant). In short arrays exist far longer in the language-concepts of C# then generics and co-variance.