# How to Convert int 2d array `int[,]` to enum 2d array `enum[,]`?

Tags: c#

I have a grid a matrix of tile.

```
enum Tile
{ 
    Nothing = 0,
    Forest = 1,
    River = 2,
    OB = 3
}

class Grid
{
    public const int X = 6;
    public const int Y = 6;
    private Tile[,] Board { get; set; } 
    public Grid()
    {
        Board = new Tile[X, Y];
    }
}
```

I want to have a Ctor that take `int[,] board`.

Edge case that are not :

- Different size. can be checked with `.GetLength(0)` to match const int X . Throw.
- Value that that are unknow `(Tile)12`, Set to default Value int =0.

So I have

```
public Grid(int[,] board)
{
    if (board.GetLength(0) != Y || board.GetLength(1) != X) { 
        throw new ArgumentException();            
    }

    Board = new Tile[Y, X];
    for (int i = 0; i < Y; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < X; j++) {
        var enumValue = (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Tile),board[i, j]))? (Tile)board[i, j]: default(Tile) ;
        Board[i, j] = enumValue;
    }
}
```

Is there a straight Foward way to cast int 2d array `int[,]` to enum 2d array `enum[,]`?

I try various combinaison of Cast, as, (). Without sucess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the way .NET was originally set up to deal with array covariance, it is actually possible to **directly cast** an array of `derived[]` to an array of `base[]`. **[This is generally considered to be a bad idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619139/covariance-and-contravariance-with-c-sharp-arrays)**

However, in the case of an `enum[]` **you can always cast to `int[]` safely.** This is because an `enum` by default is an `int` underneath. (If you have an `enum : byte` you can cast to `byte[]`.)

But C# will not let you do it easily. You need to cast to `object` first.

```cs
public Grid(int[,] board)
{
    if (board.GetLength(0) != Y || board.GetLength(1) != X) { 
        throw new ArgumentException();            
    }

    Board = (Tile[,])(object)board;
}
```

This is somewhat unsafe as it just stores the array that was passed in. If you want a copy, just call `Clone`:

```cs
public Grid(int[,] board)
{
    if (board.GetLength(0) != Y || board.GetLength(1) != X) { 
        throw new ArgumentException();            
    }

    Board = (Tile[,])board.Clone();
}
```