# Convert DataTable to Array

Tags: c#

I want to convert a `DataTable` with 10 rows or more into an **Array** like this:

```
        SqlConfiguration clist2 = new SqlConfiguration();
        clist2.QueryString = "SELECT caption_id,caption,description FROM sws_template_detail WHERE template_id = 1";

         DataTable db = clist2.GetRecords;

         ListItem datalist = new ListItem();

         foreach(DataRow row in db.Rows)
         {
             datalist = new ListItem
             {
                 id = row["caption_id"].ToString(),
                 title = row["caption"].ToString(),
                 description = row["description"].ToString()
             };
         }

         var section = new Section
         {
             title = "Title",
             items = new ListItem[]
             {
                 datalist
             }
         };
```

But the resulting data is only 1 row, how can I solve it?

Comment: You need to add the ListItem to the array inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Why an array? Why not a normal `List<T>`?

Comment: Don't use a DataTable to begin with if you want a list of items. Use an ORM like EF Core or [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) to retrieve results in the form you want. With [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) you could write just `var items=connection.Query<ListItem>("select caption_id as Id, caption as Title, description from ....").ToArray();`

Comment: `DataTable db = clist2.GetRecords;` <-- I want to know what's going on here... is `GetRecords` _really_ a property-getter? (Or is it a method and you just forgot the parentheses?)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 1 line (well, 1 statement):

```
var section = new Section
{
    title = "Title",
    items = dataTable.Rows
        .Cast<DataRow>()
        .Select( row => new ListItem()
        {
            id          = row["caption_id" ].ToString(),
            title       = row["caption"    ].ToString(),
            description = row["description"].ToString()
        } )
        .ToArray()
};
```

---

Though there's a lot of *code smells* going on here...

- Why is an class named `SqlConfiguration` being used to execute a SQL query via a property named `QueryString`.
- Public members in C#/.NET should be `PascalCase` not `camelCase`.

  - So it should be `Section.Title`, `Section.Items`, `ListItem.Id`, `ListItem.Title`, and `ListItem.Description`.
- Don't use object-initializers for *required members* of an object, because there's no compile-time guarantees that they'll be populated.

  - If a `ListItem` *must have* an `Id`, `Title`, and `Description` then they should be passed-in as constructor parameters.
- Using array-types (like `ListItem[]`) is usually not a good idea because array-types have the *worst* set of attributes in comparison to others: they're fixed-size but also mutable.

  - Whereas usually you want something resizable-and-mutable (e.g. `List<T>`) or completely immutable (e.g. `ImmutableArray<T>` or at least `IReadOnlyList<T>`).

|  | Mutable elements | Resizable | Variance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `T[]` (Array types ) | **Yes** | No | [Unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619139/covariance-and-contravariance-with-c-sharp-arrays) |
| `List<T>` | **Yes** | **Yes** | Invariant |
| `ImmutableArray<T>` | No | No | Invariant |
| `IReadOnlyList<T>` | No | No | Covariant safe |

Comment: Hai Dai, its worked for me, thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var items_array=new List<ListItem>();
         foreach(DataRow row in db.Rows)
         {
items_array.add(new ListItem
             {
                 id = row["caption_id"].ToString(),
                 title = row["caption"].ToString(),
                 description = row["description"].ToString()
             });
         }

         var section = new Section
         {
             title = "Title",
             items = items_array.toArray()
         };
```

Comment: Hai Salim Basoy, its worked for me too, thanks very much

Answer (score -1):

Loading the data into a DataTable and *then* converting it into a List wastes both CPU and RAM. You can use an ORM like EF Core or [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) to execute a query and return the results in the shape you want. For example, using Dapper, what you want is a single line:

```
var sql=@"select caption_id as Id, caption as Title, description 
FROM sws_template_detail 
WHERE template_id = 1";

var items=connection.Query<ListItem>(sql).ToArray();
```

`Query<T>` returns the results as an `IEnumerable<T>`. This is converted to an array using `ToArray()`.

Dapper allows you to easily write parameterized queries instead of concatenating strings to construct a query:

```
var sql=@"select caption_id as Id, caption as Title, description 
FROM sws_template_detail 
WHERE template_id = @id";

var items=connection.Query<ListItem>(sql,new {id=1}).ToArray();
```

The query can be executed asynchronously using `QueryAsync`;

```
var items=(await connection.QueryAsync<ListItem>(sql,new {id=1}))
          .ToArray();
```