# Assign to ICollection<BaseType> not working for List<DerivedType> but for array DerivedType[]

Tags: c#, .net

Given the following model:

```cs
public class Node {}
public class RatingNode : Node {}
public class Tree
{
  public ICollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to do the following assignment I get an error:

```cs
var tree = new Tree();
var ratingNodes = new List<RatingNode>();
tree.Nodes = ratingNodes;
```

```
Cannot convert source type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<RatingNode>' to target type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Node>'.
```

However when I use an array instead of a list then I don't get this error:

```cs
var tree = new Tree();
var ratingNodes = new RatingNode[5];
tree.Nodes = ratingNodes;
```

I don't understand why I can use an array here but not a list.
Is there some type of implicit conversion on the array that converts the `RatingNode` to `Node`?

Comment: The key-point here is that lists aren't co-variant. So even if your class `RatingNode` derives from `Node`, doesn't mean that a `List<RatingNode>` also derives from or is assignable to a `List<Node>`. Arrays on the other hand are co-variant at compile-time. However you may get a bad suprise when **executing** the code, as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619139/covariance-and-contravariance-with-c-sharp-arrays

Comment: The thing to note is that `tree.Nodes.Add(new Node())` wouldn't be a compile-time error (`Nodes` is an `ICollection<Node>` after all), but remember that the underlying storage is a `List<RatingNode>`, and this means that you'd be able to put a `Node` into a list of `RatingNodes`, which is obviously wrong! Arrays avoid this using a runtime check: `tree.Nodes[0] = new Node()` will throw an exception. This behaviour was copied from Java, but it means that every array write needs a runtime check which is expensive, and it's regarded as a mistake in C#. Generics didn't make the same mistake.