# Swift: Convert Foo<String> to Foo<Any>

Tags: ios, swift, generics, casting

here is my code

```
class Foo<T> {

}

class Main {
    static func test() {
        var foo: Foo<Any>

        var bar = Foo<String>()
        //Do all my stuff with foo necessitating String

        foo = bar
    }
}
```

When I try to assign `foo = bar` I get an error `Cannot assign a value of type Foo<String> to a value of type Foo<Any>`.
I don't understand why I got this error, since String conforms to Any.
If I do exactly the same thing but using Array, I don't have any error

```
static func test() {
        var foo: Array<Any>

        var bar = Array<String>()
        //Do all my stuff with foo necessitating String

        foo = bar
    }
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?
Thanks

Comment: try AnyObject instead of Any

Comment: Nope, same problem and besides, String does not conform to AnyObject

Comment: @Jaeger What's your use case for this? Just wondering as I experiment with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays and dictionaries are special types that have this kind of behavior built in. This does, however, not apply to custom generic types. The type `Foo<Any>` is not a supertype (or in this case superclass) of `Foo<String>` even though `Any` is a supertype of `String`. Therefore, you cannot assign variables of these types to each other.

Depending on your particular case the solution outlined in [Swift Cast Generics Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29493819/swift-cast-generics-type) might work for you. When `Foo` wraps a value of type `T` you can add a generic constructor that converts the value from a differently typed instance of `Foo`.

```
class Foo<T> {
    var val: T

    init(val: T) {
        self.val = val
    }

    init<O>(other: Foo<O>) {
        self.val = other.val as! T
    }
}

class Main {
    static func test() {
        var foo: Foo<Any>

        var bar = Foo<String>(val: "abc")
        //Do all my stuff with foo necessitating String

        foo = Foo<Any>(other: bar)
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the "specialness" of array and dict declared? Thanks.

Comment: How come foo.val.dynamicType prints Swift.String instead of Swift.Any?

Comment: @Darko Sorry, I don't know that. It's Swift internals. I think the main difference is that arrays and dictionaries are not classes but structs and probably receive special treatment by the compiler.

Comment: @WillM.That's an interesting catch. Actually, `var x: Any = "abc"; print(x.dynamicType)` prints out `Swift.String` whereas `var x: AnyObject = "abc"; print(x.dynamicType)` prints `Swift._NSContiguousString`. I guess the `Any` type just serves as a blind proxy to the underlying actual type.

Comment: @hennes I made some improvements to your answer to make it more powerful and a bit safer

Comment: @WillM. That's a nice enhancement! :)

Answer (score 2):

I have improved on @hennes answer by adding the ability to define how you want to convert from type O to type T

```
class Foo<T> {
    var val: T

    init(val: T) {
        self.val = val
    }

    init<O>(other:Foo<O>, conversion:(O) -> T) {
        self.val = conversion(other.val)
    }
}

class Main {
    static func test() {
        var foo: Foo<Int>

        var bar = Foo<String>(val: "10")
        //Do all my stuff with foo necessitating String

        foo = Foo<Int>(other: bar, conversion: {(val) in
            return Int(val.toInt()!)
        })
        print(foo.val) //prints 10
        print(foo.val.dynamicType) //prints Swift.Int
    }
}
```

This gives you the ability to convert between two types that don't support casting to each other. Additionally, it gives a compiler warning when the conversion is illegal, as opposed to crashing due to the forced cast.

No idea why there is a difference in compiler warnings for 1 or >1 line closures but there are.

Bad compiler warning for 1-line closure
[image: useless compiler warning]

Good compiler warning for 2-line closure
[image]