# How to address List<List<>> items using array [] operator

Tags: c#, arrays, list, object

Here is my problem:
I have an object "Strip" and I need to have a list or array of these strips "stripList" and after that I need to have a list from different stripList that I called it "listOfStripList". I know that I can save the in this way:

```
List<List<Strip>> listOfStripList=new List<List<Strip>>();
```

the reason that I want to have this objects in this way is because in each time I want to have access to the each stripList without using For Loop.
For example I want to say listOfStripList[1] and this related to the first list of strips.

Is there any way to define these list by Array?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: From the code snippet I would guess C#....

Comment: I know that in MATLAB when we have a matrix like A(6,6) we can use A(1,:) and it means a column of that matrix. I am looking for some thing like this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705583/indexers-in-list-vs-array

Comment: something like `Strip[][] listOfStripList`

Comment: When you say 'define' do you mean create or access?

Comment: or `List<Strip>[] arrayOfStripList`

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>` and `T[]` both allow the use of an indexer (aka the `[]` operator). So you could just use your list like the following:

```
List<Strip> firstList = listOfStripList[0];
```

Although, if you must have it as an array, you could do something like this:

```
List<Strip>[] arrayOfListStrip = listOfStripList.ToArray();
```

Comment: Not exactly. `T[]` and `List<T>` both allow the syntax `obj[index]`, yes, but for different reasons, and with no relation to the fact that they implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Ah.. That was just an assumption. I guess I should look stuff like that up. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

`listOfStripList[0]` would give you a `List<Strip>`  object.  Calling `listOfStripList[0][0]` should give you the first item in the first list in `listOfStripList`

Here's a fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/XdDggB

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<List<Strip>> listOfStripLists = new List<List<Strip>>();

        for(int j = 65; j < 100; j++){

            List<Strip> stripList = new List<Strip>();

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                stripList.Add(new Strip(){myval = ((char)j).ToString() + i.ToString()});
            }

            listOfStripLists.Add(stripList);
        }// end list of list

        Console.WriteLine(listOfStripLists[0][1].myval);
    }


    public class Strip
    {
        public string myval {get;set;}  
    }
}
```