# How to get MemberInfo of ArrayLength type expressions?

Tags: c#, expression-trees, memberinfo

Some trouble with `UnaryExpression`s.

**This works** this way:

```
Expression<Func<List<string>, object>> k = l => l.Count;
//got member in this case like this
var member = ((k.Body as UnaryExpression).Operand as MemberExpression).Member;
```

In the above case the `k.Body.NodeType` was `ExpressionType.Convert`. But it's a little tricky with `ExpressionType.ArrayLength`. **How would I get the `PropertyInfo` `member` similarly in the below case?:**

```
Expression<Func<string[], int>> k = l => l.Length;
var member = ??
```

In the second case `k.Body` is something like `ArrayLength(l)`.

I can do it with a hack like this:

```
var member = (k.Body as UnaryExpression).Operand.Type.GetProperty("Length");
```

**but this doesn't feel like a straight forward expression approach**. It's more a plain old reflection call with dirty string "Length" passed. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an `ArrayLength` node, which you can create with the [`Expression.ArrayLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.arraylength%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) method.

It's just a `UnaryExpression` with an `Operand` which is the array expression, and a `NodeType` of `ArrayLength`. It's not entirely clear to me what you wanted to know about it, but hopefully the call to `Expression.ArrayLength` is what you were after.

EDIT: Although there *is* an [`Array.Length` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx), that's not what's used normally. For example:

```
int[] x = new int[10];
Array y = x;

int a = x.Length;
int b = y.Length;
```

... then evaluating `x.Length` uses the `ldlen` IL instruction whereas evaluating `y.Length` uses a call to the property.

Comment: I want to know how to get the `PropertyInfo` of `Length` property from `l.Length` part of the expression. How do I get that from `Expression.ArrayLength` method?

Comment: @nawfal: It's not a property, so there *is* no such `PropertyInfo`.

Comment: I guess it is a property. For instance I can get the `PropertyInfo` of a typical `int[].Length` like `typeof(int[]).GetProperty("Length")`.

Comment: @nawfal: Sorry, to clarify - that's the `Array.Property` length, but if you use `int[] x = ...; int y = x.Length;` then that *doesn't* use the property.

Comment: Then what does it use ultimately? If anything shouldn't it have a `MemberInfo` associated with it?

Comment: @nawfal: No, it's special basically. See my edit for more details.