# What does "a field initializer cannot reference non static fields" mean in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

I don't understand this error in C#

> error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Prv.DB.getUserName(long)'

For the following code

```
public class MyDictionary<K, V>
{
    public delegate V NonExistentKey(K k);
    NonExistentKey nonExistentKey;

    public MyDictionary(NonExistentKey nonExistentKey_) { }
}

class DB
{
    SQLiteConnection connection;
    SQLiteCommand command;

    MyDictionary<long, string> usernameDict = new MyDictionary<long, string>(getUserName);

    string getUserName(long userId) { }
}
```

Comment: Think about what would happen if the MyDictionary ctor invoked the passed delegate immediately. _It would call a method on an object whose constructor was still running!_ That could be very bad. Therefore, it's illegal to pass a delegate to an instance member like this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Any object initializer used outside a constructor has to refer to static members, as the instance hasn't been constructed until the constructor is run, and direct variable initialization conceptually happens before any constructor is run. getUserName is an instance method, but the containing instance isn't available.

To fix it, try putting the usernameDict initializer inside a constructor.

Answer (score 8):

The links below may shed some light on why doing what you are trying to do may not be such a good thing, in particular the second link:

[Why Do Initializers Run In The Opposite Order As Constructors? Part One](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one)

[Why Do Initializers Run In The Opposite Order As Constructors? Part Two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two)

Comment: The links are great background on the "why" part.

Answer (score 2):

getUserName is an instance method.
Change it to static, that might work.

OR

Initialize the dictionary in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this because the instance has to be initialized before you can access the properties of its class. The field initializers are called before the class is initialized.

If you want to initialize the field usernameDict with the return-value of the GetUserName-Method you have to do it within the constructor or make the Method a static one.